# Getting all types that implement an interface

Tags: c#, optimization, reflection, lambda, c#-3.0

Using reflection, how can I get all types that implement an interface with C# 3.0/.NET 3.5 with the least code, and minimizing iterations?

This is what I want to re-write:

```
foreach (Type t in this.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes())
    if (t is IMyInterface)
        ; //do stuff
```

Comment: Does the example code works? I've got false negatives with your if condition.

Comment: The if statement in the code above will always be false because you are testing if an instance of the Type class (t) implements your interface which it won't unless Type inherits IMyInterface (in which case it will always be true).

Answer (score 946, accepted):

Mine would be this in c# 3.0 :)

```
var type = typeof(IMyInterface);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p));
```

Basically, the least amount of iterations will always be:

```
loop assemblies  
 loop types  
  see if implemented.
```

Comment: Note that the list may also include the interface itself. Change the last line to `.Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p) && !p.IsInterface);` to filter it out (or `p.IsClass`).

Comment: Note:This answer is wrong!, this checks "Assignment compatibility" not whether interface is implemented are not. For example `List<string>` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<object>` but this method will return true in .Net 4.0 due to covariance which is wrong indeed. [Correct answer is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12602220/2530848)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel first off, generic values weren't specified. Second, this question pre-dates covariance. Third, you make the assumption that covariant return is not something they want.

Comment: You're absolutely right darren, I know this is a old thread, I just registered my comment just for the future users to make aware of such problem exist. Not to offend you. and as question title says if OP is asking for *Getting all types that implement an interface* this code isn't doing that. but almost all the cases **it works**, no doubt. there are corner cases too as I said. Just to be aware of it;

Comment: Also, there's no need to declare `var type = typeof(IMyInterface)` because `typeof(IMyInterface)` is evaluated at compile-time, and isn't re-evaluated over and over when in the `Where` statement.

Comment: Will also need to make sure the class isn't abstract => `.Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass && !p.IsAbstract`

Comment: @Jonesopolis the asker didn't specify if they wanted to instantiate the class or not. abstract classes can still implement interfaces and may be what you want to look for depending on what you are doing.

Comment: @DarrenKopp good call.  I had just made the assumption he was looking for instantiatable classes, I was when I found this question.

Comment: make sure your assembly with the interface is included within the bin folder so that this code can pick it up, that was my problem

Comment: I tried it for the classes which implementing from the Interface. It works fine. But why doesn't it work for the abstract class?

Comment: Add using: `using System;` and `using System.Reflection` and `using System.Linq` for beginners.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel That sounds intesting, sadly googling for it I wasn't able to find anything. Can you tell me some keywords for the covariance thing so I can look it up?

Comment: @snowflake Eric's article should help https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/30/whats-the-difference-between-covariance-and-assignment-compatibility/. Google with keywords like "Eric lippert covariance" you will get lot of hits

Comment: I'd like to add that checking if the type is not abstract rules out both interfaces and abstract classes, so `.Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p) && !p.IsAbstract)` should be enough.

Comment: When I try this solution, I get an error trying to get classes from an external assembly. [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12602220/1025320) worked better in my case.

Comment: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` might not contain all assemblies & types that you are expecting because some of these assemblies will be loaded at runtime based on need.
check https://stackoverflow.com/a/2479400/1371297

Comment: This answer searches too many assemblies. You only need the assemblies referencing the interface assembly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66900943/1546844

Comment: In .NET 5 this valid marked solution won't work.

This works, for example to auto wire classes that share the same interface (strategy pattern, where ITemplateParser is the shared interface):

var assemblyWithWorkers = typeof(AnyClassThatImplementsITemplateParser).Assembly;

            foreach (var type in assemblyWithWorkers.GetTypes()
                                                    .Where(t => t.IsClass && typeof(ITemplateParser).IsAssignableFrom(t)))
            {
                serviceCollection.AddScoped(type);
            }

Comment: @chtenb Actually, this will iterate less assemblies than your solution. First, your solution will still iterate every single assembly, and then it will iterate every one of the referencing assemblies of every assembly. That's quickly approaching O(n^2).

Comment: @maksymiuk it's not about iterating assemblies, it's about loading and iterating all types in all assemblies. My answer does not load all types for all assemblies, while this answer does

Answer (score 96):

This worked for me. It loops though the classes and checks to see if they are derrived from myInterface

```
 foreach (Type mytype in System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                 .Where(mytype => mytype .GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(myInterface)))) {
    //do stuff
 }
```

Comment: You are assuming the assembly is in the main executable.  Not an additional project.  You are also iterating unnecessarily though a bunch of iterations.  It is better to have the framework do the heavy lifting.  Then filter down farther when found.  If relevant, please update your answer. Include List<T> reasoning.  var classTypesImplementingInterface = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()).Where(mytype => typeof(myInterface).IsAssignableFrom(mytype) && mytype.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(myInterface))); foreach(var item in items) Console.Log(item.Name);

Comment: this worked for me even as my assembly was in an additional project. However, it brought me an `InvalidCastException` down the line, so using `.IsAssignableFrom(..)` might be safer if one actually wants to actually cast to that interface later.

Answer (score 85):

Other answers use some form of [`Assembly.GetTypes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Whilst GetTypes() will indeed return all types, it does not necessarily mean you could activate them and could thus potentially throw a [`ReflectionTypeLoadException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.reflectiontypeloadexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

A classic example for not being able to activate a type would be when the type returned is `derived` from `base` but `base` is defined in a different assembly from that of `derived`, an assembly that the calling assembly does not reference.

So say we have:

```
Class A // in AssemblyA
Class B : Class A, IMyInterface // in AssemblyB
Class C // in AssemblyC which references AssemblyB but not AssemblyA
```

If in `ClassC` which is in `AssemblyC` we then do something as per accepted answer:

```
var type = typeof(IMyInterface);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p));
```

Then it will throw a [`ReflectionTypeLoadException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.reflectiontypeloadexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This is because without a reference to `AssemblyA`  in `AssemblyC` you would not be able to:

```
var bType = typeof(ClassB);
var bClass = (ClassB)Activator.CreateInstance(bType);
```

In other words `ClassB` is not *loadable* which is something that the call to GetTypes checks and throws on.

So to safely qualify the result set for loadable types then as per this [Phil Haacked](http://haacked.com/) article [Get All Types in an Assembly](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/23/get-all-types-in-an-assembly.aspx/) and [Jon Skeet code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889228/how-to-prevent-reflectiontypeloadexception-when-calling-assembly-gettypes) you would instead do something like:

```
public static class TypeLoaderExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetLoadableTypes(this Assembly assembly) {
        if (assembly == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("assembly");
        try {
            return assembly.GetTypes();
        } catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e) {
            return e.Types.Where(t => t != null);
        }
    }
}
```

And then:

```
private IEnumerable<Type> GetTypesWithInterface(Assembly asm) {
    var it = typeof (IMyInterface);
    return asm.GetLoadableTypes().Where(it.IsAssignableFrom).ToList();
}
```

Comment: This helped me deal with a super weird problem, where in my test project GetTypes would fail and only in our CI-environment. GetLoadableTypes was a fix for this solution. The error wouldn't be reproducible in the local environment and it was this: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information. More specifically it was complaining that there was a type that didn't have a concrete implementation and it happened in the unit test project. Thanks for this!

Comment: This answer should be marked as solution, it saved my ass today, because like @Lari Tuomisto said, on local env we couldn't re-product similar error

Comment: In case it helps someone else: this solution worked for me, but I had to modify it to remove the interface type from the list. I wanted to activate `CreateInstance` for all of them, and an exception was thrown when it was trying to create the actual interface (which had me confused for a while when I thought the actual interface was out of the way in this solution). So I changed the code to `GetLoadableTypes(assembly).Where(interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom).Where(t => !(t.Equals(interfaceType))).ToList();`.

Answer (score 66):

To find all types in an assembly that implement IFoo interface:

```
var results = from type in someAssembly.GetTypes()
              where typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(type)
              select type;
```

Note that Ryan Rinaldi's suggestion was incorrect. It will return 0 types. You cannot write

```
where type is IFoo
```

because type is a System.Type instance, and will never be of type IFoo. Instead, you check to see if IFoo is assignable from the type. That will get your expected results.

Also, Adam Wright's suggestion, which is currently marked as the answer, is incorrect as well, and for the same reason. At runtime, you'll see 0 types come back, because all System.Type instances weren't IFoo implementors.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The accepted answer doesn't work.

Comment: this also returns the interface itself. Looks like the question is asking only to return the types of classes where the interface is inherited, but not the interface itself. Best.

Comment: Agreed.  This is the correct answer.

Also, since I like the lambda syntax, it can be written as 

var results = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(t))
    .Select(t => t).ToList();

Answer (score 24):

Other answers here use `IsAssignableFrom`.  You can also use `FindInterfaces` from the `System` namespace, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.findinterfaces%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Here's an example that checks all assemblies in the currently executing assembly's folder, looking for classes that implement a certain interface (avoiding LINQ for clarity).

```
static void Main() {
    const string qualifiedInterfaceName = "Interfaces.IMyInterface";
    var interfaceFilter = new TypeFilter(InterfaceFilter);
    var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    var di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    foreach (var file in di.GetFiles("*.dll")) {
        try {
            var nextAssembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(file.FullName);
            foreach (var type in nextAssembly.GetTypes()) {
                var myInterfaces = type.FindInterfaces(interfaceFilter, qualifiedInterfaceName);
                if (myInterfaces.Length > 0) {
                    // This class implements the interface
                }
            }
        } catch (BadImageFormatException) {
            // Not a .net assembly  - ignore
        }
    }
}

public static bool InterfaceFilter(Type typeObj, Object criteriaObj) {
    return typeObj.ToString() == criteriaObj.ToString();
}
```

You can set up a list of interfaces if you want to match more than one.

Comment: This one looks for string interface name which is what I was looking for.

Comment: Works when loading an assembly in a different domain, as the type has to be serialized into a string. very awesome!

Comment: I get: Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.

Answer (score 19):

loop through all loaded assemblies, loop through all their types, and check if they implement the interface.

something like:

```
Type ti = typeof(IYourInterface);
foreach (Assembly asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) {
    foreach (Type t in asm.GetTypes()) {
        if (ti.IsAssignableFrom(t)) {
            // here's your type in t
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me (if you wish you could exclude system types in the lookup):

```
Type lookupType = typeof (IMenuItem);
IEnumerable<Type> lookupTypes = GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().Where(
        t => lookupType.IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsInterface);
```

Answer (score 12):

Other answer were not working with a **generic interface**.

This one does, just replace typeof(ISomeInterface) by typeof (T).

```
List<string> types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
            .Where(x => typeof(ISomeInterface).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsInterface && !x.IsAbstract)
            .Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

So with

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
```

we get all the assemblies

```
!x.IsInterface && !x.IsAbstract
```

is used to exclude the interface and abstract ones and

```
.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

to have them in a list.

Comment: Please explain how your solution works and why it is superior to all the other answers.

Comment: It is not superior or lower, the other answers didn't work for me and I bothered to share it.

Comment: My comment was just about your answer being code-only, so I asked you to add some explanation.

Answer (score 9):

I see so many overcomplicated answers here and people always tell me that I tend to overcomplicate things. Also using `IsAssignableFrom` method for the purpose of solving OP problem is wrong!

Here is my example, it selects all assemblies from the app domain, then it takes flat list of all available types and checks every single type's list of interfaces for match:

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetImplementingTypes(this Type itype) 
    => AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
           .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(itype));
```

Answer (score 6):

All the answers posted thus far either take too few or too many assemblies into account. You need to only inspect the assemblies that reference the assembly containing the interface. This minimizes the number of static constructors being run unnecessarily and save a huge amount of time and possibly unexpected side effects in the case of third party assemblies.

```
public static class ReflectionUtils
{
    public static bool DoesTypeSupportInterface(Type type, Type inter)
    {
        if (inter.IsAssignableFrom(type))
            return true;
        if (type.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == inter))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetReferencingAssemblies(Assembly assembly)
    {
        return AppDomain
            .CurrentDomain
            .GetAssemblies().Where(asm => asm.GetReferencedAssemblies().Any(asmName => AssemblyName.ReferenceMatchesDefinition(asmName, assembly.GetName())));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> TypesImplementingInterface(Type desiredType)
    {
        var assembliesToSearch = new Assembly[] { desiredType.Assembly }
            .Concat(GetReferencingAssemblies(desiredType.Assembly));
        return assembliesToSearch.SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
            .Where(type => DoesTypeSupportInterface(type, desiredType));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> NonAbstractTypesImplementingInterface(Type desiredType)
    {
        return TypesImplementingInterface(desiredType).Where(t => !t.IsAbstract);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Edit: I've just seen the edit to clarify that the original question was for the reduction of iterations / code and that's all well and good as an exercise, but in real-world situations you're going to want the fastest implementation, regardless of how cool the underlying LINQ looks.

Here's my Utils method for iterating through the loaded types.  It handles regular classes as well as interfaces, and the excludeSystemTypes option speeds things up hugely if you are looking for implementations in your own / third-party codebase.

```
public static List<Type> GetSubclassesOf(this Type type, bool excludeSystemTypes) {
    List<Type> list = new List<Type>();
    IEnumerator enumerator = Thread.GetDomain().GetAssemblies().GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
        try {
            Type[] types = ((Assembly) enumerator.Current).GetTypes();
            if (!excludeSystemTypes || (excludeSystemTypes && !((Assembly) enumerator.Current).FullName.StartsWith("System."))) {
                IEnumerator enumerator2 = types.GetEnumerator();
                while (enumerator2.MoveNext()) {
                    Type current = (Type) enumerator2.Current;
                    if (type.IsInterface) {
                        if (current.GetInterface(type.FullName) != null) {
                            list.Add(current);
                        }
                    } else if (current.IsSubclassOf(type)) {
                        list.Add(current);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

It's not pretty, I'll admit.

Comment: Enumerators implement IDisposable which isn't being disposed in a try/finally. It is better to use a foreach or linq.

Comment: Why are you testing `excludeSystemTypes` twice in one `if`?

Answer (score 4):

Even better when choosing the Assembly location. Filter most of the assemblies if you know all your implemented interfaces are within the same Assembly.DefinedTypes.

```
// We get the assembly through the base class
var baseAssembly = typeof(baseClass).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

// we filter the defined classes according to the interfaces they implement
var typeList = baseAssembly.DefinedTypes.Where(type => type.ImplementedInterfaces.Any(inter => inter == typeof(IMyInterface))).ToList();
```

[By Can Bilgin](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/abf6e015-3ece-4eab-85c9-d1878a5135e6/reflection-getting-all-classes-that-implement-a-given-interface?forum=winappswithcsharp)

Answer (score 3):

There's no easy way (in terms of performance) to do what you want to do.

Reflection works with assemblys and types mainly so you'll have to get all the types of the assembly and query them for the right interface. Here's an example:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("MyAssembly");
Type[] types = asm.GetTypes();
Type[] result = types.where(x => x.GetInterface("IMyInterface") != null);
```

That will get you all the types that implement the IMyInterface in the Assembly MyAssembly

Answer (score 1):

There are many valid answers already but I'd like to add anther implementation as a Type extension and a list of unit tests to demonstrate different scenarios:

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetAllTypes(this Type type)
    {
        var typeInfo = type.GetTypeInfo();
        var allTypes = GetAllImplementedTypes(type).Concat(typeInfo.ImplementedInterfaces);
        return allTypes;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Type> GetAllImplementedTypes(Type type)
    {
        yield return type;
        var typeInfo = type.GetTypeInfo();
        var baseType = typeInfo.BaseType;
        if (baseType != null)
        {
            foreach (var foundType in GetAllImplementedTypes(baseType))
            {
                yield return foundType;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This algorithm supports the following scenarios:

```
public static class GetAllTypesTests
{
    public class Given_A_Sample_Standalone_Class_Type_When_Getting_All_Types
        : Given_When_Then_Test
    {
        private Type _sut;
        private IEnumerable<Type> _expectedTypes;
        private IEnumerable<Type> _result;

        protected override void Given()
        {
            _sut = typeof(SampleStandalone);

            _expectedTypes =
                new List<Type>
                {
                    typeof(SampleStandalone),
                    typeof(object)
                };
        }

        protected override void When()
        {
            _result = _sut.GetAllTypes();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Then_It_Should_Return_The_Right_Type()
        {
            _result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(_expectedTypes);
        }
    }

    public class Given_A_Sample_Abstract_Base_Class_Type_When_Getting_All_Types
        : Given_When_Then_Test
    {
        private Type _sut;
        private IEnumerable<Type> _expectedTypes;
        private IEnumerable<Type> _result;

        protected override void Given()
        {
            _sut = typeof(SampleBase);

            _expectedTypes =
                new List<Type>
                {
                    typeof(SampleBase),
                    typeof(object)
                };
        }

        protected override void When()
        {
            _result = _sut.GetAllTypes();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Then_It_Should_Return_The_Right_Type()
        {
            _result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(_expectedTypes);
        }
    }

    public class Given_A_Sample_Child_Class_Type_When_Getting_All_Types
        : Given_When_Then_Test
    {
        private Type _sut;
        private IEnumerable<Type> _expectedTypes;
        private IEnumerable<Type> _result;

        protected override void Given()
        {
            _sut = typeof(SampleChild);

            _expectedTypes =
                new List<Type>
                {
                    typeof(SampleChild),
                    typeof(SampleBase),
                    typeof(object)
                };
        }

        protected override void When()
        {
            _result = _sut.GetAllTypes();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Then_It_Should_Return_The_Right_Type()
        {
            _result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(_expectedTypes);
        }
    }

    public class Given_A_Sample_Base_Interface_Type_When_Getting_All_Types
        : Given_When_Then_Test
    {
        private Type _sut;
        private IEnumerable<Type> _expectedTypes;
        private IEnumerable<Type> _result;

        protected override void Given()
        {
            _sut = typeof(ISampleBase);

            _expectedTypes =
                new List<Type>
                {
                    typeof(ISampleBase)
                };
        }

        protected override void When()
        {
            _result = _sut.GetAllTypes();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Then_It_Should_Return_The_Right_Type()
        {
            _result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(_expectedTypes);
        }
    }

    public class Given_A_Sample_Child_Interface_Type_When_Getting_All_Types
        : Given_When_Then_Test
    {
        private Type _sut;
        private IEnumerable<Type> _expectedTypes;
        private IEnumerable<Type> _result;

        protected override void Given()
        {
            _sut = typeof(ISampleChild);

            _expectedTypes =
                new List<Type>
                {
                    typeof(ISampleBase),
                    typeof(ISampleChild)
                };
        }

        protected override void When()
        {
            _result = _sut.GetAllTypes();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Then_It_Should_Return_The_Right_Type()
        {
            _result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(_expectedTypes);
        }
    }

    public class Given_A_Sample_Implementation_Class_Type_When_Getting_All_Types
        : Given_When_Then_Test
    {
        private Type _sut;
        private IEnumerable<Type> _expectedTypes;
        private IEnumerable<Type> _result;

        protected override void Given()
        {
            _sut = typeof(SampleImplementation);

            _expectedTypes =
                new List<Type>
                {
                    typeof(SampleImplementation),
                    typeof(SampleChild),
                    typeof(SampleBase),
                    typeof(ISampleChild),
                    typeof(ISampleBase),
                    typeof(object)
                };
        }

        protected override void When()
        {
            _result = _sut.GetAllTypes();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Then_It_Should_Return_The_Right_Type()
        {
            _result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(_expectedTypes);
        }
    }

    public class Given_A_Sample_Interface_Instance_Type_When_Getting_All_Types
        : Given_When_Then_Test
    {
        private Type _sut;
        private IEnumerable<Type> _expectedTypes;
        private IEnumerable<Type> _result;

        class Foo : ISampleChild { }

        protected override void Given()
        {
            var foo = new Foo();
            _sut = foo.GetType();

            _expectedTypes =
                new List<Type>
                {
                    typeof(Foo),
                    typeof(ISampleChild),
                    typeof(ISampleBase),
                    typeof(object)
                };
        }

        protected override void When()
        {
            _result = _sut.GetAllTypes();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Then_It_Should_Return_The_Right_Type()
        {
            _result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(_expectedTypes);
        }
    }

    sealed class SampleStandalone { }
    abstract class SampleBase { }
    class SampleChild : SampleBase { }
    interface ISampleBase { }
    interface ISampleChild : ISampleBase { }
    class SampleImplementation : SampleChild, ISampleChild { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it helps anyone, this is what I'm using to make some of my unit tests easier :)

```
public static Type GetInterfacesImplementation(this Type type)
{
    return type.Assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p) && !p.IsInterface)
        .SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got exceptions in the linq-code so I do it this way (without a complicated extension):

```
private static IList<Type> loadAllImplementingTypes(Type[] interfaces)
{
    IList<Type> implementingTypes = new List<Type>();

    // find all types
    foreach (var interfaceType in interfaces)
        foreach (var currentAsm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            try
            {
                foreach (var currentType in currentAsm.GetTypes())
                    if (interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(currentType) && currentType.IsClass && !currentType.IsAbstract)
                        implementingTypes.Add(currentType);
            }
            catch { }

    return implementingTypes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OfType Linq method can be used exactly for this kind of scenarios:

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score -1):

```
   public IList<T> GetClassByType<T>()
   {
        return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                          .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                          .ToList(p => typeof(T)
                          .IsAssignableFrom(p) && !p.IsAbstract && !p.IsInterface)
                          .SelectList(c => (T)Activator.CreateInstance(c));
   }
```

Answer (score -4):

You could use some LINQ to get the list:

```
var types = from type in this.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
            where type is ISomeInterface
            select type;
```

But really, is that more readable?

Comment: It might be more readable, if it worked. Unfortunately, your where clause is checking to see if an instance of the System.Type class implements ISomeInterface, which will never be true, unless ISomeInterface is really IReflect or ICustomAttributeProvider, in which case it will always be true.

Comment: Carl Nayak answer above has the answer to correcting the where clause: IsAssignableFrom. Easy mistake for an answer.