# How to find all the classes which implement a given interface?

Tags: c#, reflection

Under a given namespace, I have a set of classes which implement an interface. Let's call it `ISomething`. I have another class (let's call it `CClass`) which knows about `ISomething` but doesn't know about the classes which implement that interface.

I would like that `CClass` to look for all the implementation of `ISomething`, instantiate an instance of it and execute the method.

Does anybody have an idea on how to do that with C# 3.5?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting all types that implement an interface with C# 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface-with-c-sharp-3-0)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

A working code-sample:

```
var instances = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                where t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ISomething))
                         && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
                select Activator.CreateInstance(t) as ISomething;

foreach (var instance in instances)
{
    instance.Foo(); // where Foo is a method of ISomething
}
```

**Edit** Added a check for a parameterless constructor so that the call to CreateInstance will succeed.

Comment: Tiny clean up suggestion -- use Type.EmptyTypes instead of instantiating a new empty Type array.

Comment: Is there a way to do this across all loaded assemblies?

Comment: nevermind..

var instances = from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                from t in assembly.GetTypes()
                where t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ISomething))
                         && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
                select Activator.CreateInstance(t) as ISomething;

Comment: Nice! I haven't had to try that since I started using MEF. :)

Comment: +1: I have a code snippet that just uses old-school reflection, but this is much nicer.

Comment: +1 Matt - a well late tick for this one. i particularly like the combination of this along with gregmac's addition, works great

Answer (score 11):

You can get a list of loaded assemblies by using this:

```
Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
```

From there, you can get a list of types in the assembly (assuming public types):

```
Type[] types = assembly.GetExportedTypes();
```

Then you can ask each type whether it supports that interface by finding that interface on the object:

```
Type interfaceType = type.GetInterface("ISomething");
```

Not sure if there is a more efficient way of doing this with reflection.

Answer (score 9):

A example using Linq:

```
var types =
  myAssembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(m => m.IsClass && m.GetInterface("IMyInterface") != null);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (Type t in Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetTypes())
{
    if (t.GetInterface("ITheInterface") != null)
    {
        ITheInterface executor = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as ITheInterface;
        executor.PerformSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like the following and tailor it to your needs.

```
var _interfaceType = typeof(ISomething);
var currentAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var types = GetType().GetNestedTypes();

foreach (var type in types)
{
    if (_interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(type) && type.IsPublic && !type.IsInterface)
    {
        ISomething something = (ISomething)currentAssembly.CreateInstance(type.FullName, false);
        something.TheMethod();
    }
}
```

This code could use some performance enhancements but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we should go this way

```
foreach ( var instance in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(a => a.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null).Select(Activator.CreateInstance).OfType<ISomething>() ) 
   instance.Execute();
```