# Creating a collection of all classes that inherit from IBlahblah

Tags: c#, oop, reflection

Using reflection (i'm guessing?), is it possible to create a method that will return a collection of all objects that inherit from an interface named IBlahblah?

```
public interface IBlahblah;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you have an assembly (or a list of assemblies) to look in, you can get a collection of *types* which implement an interface:

```
var blahs = assembly.GetTypes()
                    .Where(t => typeof(IBlahblah).IsAssignableFrom(t));
```

You can't get a collection of "live objects" implementing the interface though - at least not without using the debugging/profiling API or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

[Do you mean something like this ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface-with-c-3-5)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible, this other stack overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699852/how-to-find-all-the-classes-which-implement-a-given-interface) gives the solution with LINQ.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible :

```
    var result = new List<Type>();
    foreach(var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        foreach(var type in assembly.GetTypes())
            if (typeof(IBlahblah).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                result.Add(type);
```

And this includes the types outside of the current assembly.