# get a list of C# classes which implement a given interface

Tags: c#, interface

Is there a way to get a list of the system C# classes which implement a given interface?  In particular, I'm interested in IDrawable at present.  But I imagine this will come up again, for other interfaces.

EDIT:  Preferably in the documentation, not in code as the "possible duplicate" does.  To do it in code, I'd have to link all the relevant assemblies.  But I don't know which assemblies are relevant.

Comment: With `R#`, you can right click on the Interface, and click **find usages**

Comment: If you don't know which assemblies are relevant, how do you know what documentation to search?

Comment: I don't.  That's why I'm asking.  At any rate, the answer to my question appears to be "No".

Answer (score 1):

For documentation, the answer appears to be "no".  However, if one has linked the appropriate assemblies, one can find the answer in code as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699852/how-to-find-all-the-classes-which-implement-a-given-interface)