# Selecting classes from a list of a derived interface

Tags: c#

I have a List of an interface:

```
private IList<IPlugin> plugins;
```

I want to have an accessor method that allows the user to get a list of implementers of said interface:

```
public IList<T> GetPlugins<T>() where T : IPlugin
{
   // Create list
}
```

I have looked at multiple examples where the Assembly is iterated. I have already achieved that as I am using MEF and so my `plugins` are already populated with the exported classes that inherit IPlugin.

The problem I have had is that the methods that use the Assembly do not translate over in to my List setup. I am not as versed in linq to know what is different between what the other questions used versus what i am trying to achieve.

These are the questions that i have looked at:

- [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699852/how-to-find-all-the-classes-which-implement-a-given-interface)
- [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface)

**Edit for clarity:**

Let's say I have some classes:

```
public class Setting : IPlugin {}
public class AppearanceSetting : Setting {}
public class WebSettings : Setting {}
```

If i have a list of IPlugin and i want to use my accessor call from above.

```
var settings = GetPlugins<Setting>(); // Get all implementors of Setting
```

How can i do that from a `List`? The examples i have found all use the Assembly. But if i have already done that using MEF, what is the best way to manipulate IList to get the classes I need?  If it is even possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is - you have creates a list of `IPlugin` objects but are not sure how to access it?

Comment: You need to be a bit clearer as to what is going wrong

Comment: Are you asking where to find [Type.FullName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I made an addition to clarify my question. Sorry for the vagueness originally.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'm still missing whats so special about the list thing. Are you just looking for `OfType`?

Comment: I don't want all instances. There could be an item in the list like `public class Tool : IPlugin{}` That I wouldn't want to return but would still exist in the original list.

Comment: I didn't even think to use OfType as I have never had to use it before. Let me give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get plugin classes that way:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Linq;

IEnumerable<Type> getAllTheTypes() {
    return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(ass => ass.GetTypes());
}
IEnumerable<Type> getPluginTypes<T>() where T : IPlugin {
    return getAllTheTypes()
        .Where(typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom);
}
IEnumerable<Type> getPluginClassesWithDefaultConstructor<T>() where T : IPlugin {
    return getPluginTypes<T>()
        .Where(cls => !cls.IsAbstract)
        .Where(cls => cls.GetConstructor(new Type[] { }) != null);
}
```

You can instantiate them and make list:

```cs
List<T> makePlugins<T>() where T : IPlugin {
    return getPluginClassesWithDefaultConstructor<T>()
        .Select(cls => (T)cls.GetConstructor(new Type[] { }).Invoke(new object[] { }))
        .ToList();
}
```

But if you just need to convert `List<IPlugin>` to `List<Setting>`, `plugins.OfType<Setting>().ToList()` might be what you want