# XmlSerializer can't deserialize its own output when "extraTypes" are provided

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, xml-serialization

I've encountered a situation where `XmlSerializer` can't deserialize back its own output. The data structure basically consists of a root class `Project` containing a `ProjectItems` property (of a custom collection type) holding individual items. Some items may contain nested items recursively.

```
public class Project
{
    [XmlElement("ProjectItem")]
    public ProjectItemCollection { get; set; }
}
```

The XML produced by `XmlSerializer` looks like this:

```
<Project>
    <ProjectItem xsi:type="ContentOrganizationPlanProjectItem">
        <ProjectItem xsi:type="FolderProjectItem">
        </ProjectItem>
        <ProjectItem xsi:type="FolderProjectItem">
        </ProjectItem>
    </ProjectItem>
</Project>
```

*Note: All unimportant stuff is removed from the code examples.*

Originally I had the `ProjectItem` class decorated with `XmlInclude` attributes to cover all the various types of items that may occur in the data structure. That worked fine.

However, as it needs to be extensible from independent assemblies, I had to replace these attributes with a dynamically constructed array of all possible types passed to `XmlSerializer` constructor's `extraTypes` parameter using [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689566/how-to-add-xmlinclude-attribute-dynamically/2689660#2689660).

Again—serialization works just fine. The problem is that when I try to deserialize it back, `XmlSerializer` throws an `InvalidCastException` saying:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.XmlNode[]' to type 'Whatever.ProjectItem'.

How do I make `XmlSerializer` deserialize its own output it this case?

---

*Side note: I can't withstand dancing the `XmlSerializer` bullets anymore—[Trinity, help!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vs3OS-JMyU)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was trivial indeed:

```
public class Project
{
    [XmlElement("ProjectItem", typeof(ProjectItem))]
    public ProjectItemCollection { get; set; }
}
```

Specifying the `typeof(ProjectItem)` in `XmlElement` is useless for serialization. However, it's **crucial for deserialization**.

Answer (score 0):

If you continue to struggle with the XmlSerializer, you might find the XAML serialization (which is moved out of WPF and now is completly available in it's own System.Xaml.dll) helpful. It is really powerful and extendable.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll definitely check it out. Actually I was—again—pretty damn close to writing a `XmlSerializer` replacement. It just plain sucks.