# How to serialize derived classes in a Xml?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

Imagine this is my scenario:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public abstract int X { get; set; }
}

public class FooA : Foo
{
    public override int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}

public class FooB : Foo
{
    public override int X { get; set; }
    public int Z { get; set; }
}
```

This is a service where I've got some objects to serialize.

```
public class FooService
{
    public List<Foo> GetModels()
    {
        return new List<Foo>()
        {
            new FooA() { X = 3, Y = 6 },
            new FooB() { X = 5, Z = 10 }
        };
    }
}
```

And this is the method where I can't serialize my objects, it throws an exception. I want to serialize derived classes.

```
    private void SerializeObjects()
    {
        FooService service = new FooService();
        var a = service.GetModels();

        XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(a.GetType());
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("A.xml");

        x.Serialize(writer, a);
        writer.Close();
    }
```

Comment: What is the exception? What have you tried?

Comment: What's the exception text?  I bet it's complaining about known types and telling you what to do about it.

Comment: @Vache this is my error: There was an error generating the XML document.

Comment: There's no XML Attribute declarations on any of those classes.  You have to tell the serializer what to serialise by decorating properties and attributes of Foo, FooA, FooB etc

Comment: And the inner exception tells you to `"The type FooA was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically."` :-)

Comment: @EricJ. It works :), allow me to make clear my situation. I've got a library where it has ´Foo´, and another modules contains FooA and FooB. I mean, I need to create many modules and I don't prefer put those Includes.. what might I do?

Comment: @DarfZon Use some other serializers like [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @L.B: Json.Net can handle types that are not statically known?  DataContractSerializer cannot... would surprise me if Json.Net can.

Comment: @DarfZon: Added more info to the answer based on "many modules"

Comment: @EricJ. This is the output `[{"X":3,"Y":6},{"X":5,"Z":10}]` of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(service.GetModels())`

Answer (score 12):

You have to tell the serializer about the derived types

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(FooA))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(FooB))]
public abstract class Foo
{
    public abstract int X { get; set; }
}
```

This is one of the choice .Net exceptions that are truly helpful.  If you look at the InnerException, you will see

> The type FooA was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude
>   attribute to specify types that are not known statically.

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment about many derived types in different modules, you can also specify derived types at runtime when creating the serializer rather than at compile time:

[How to add XmlInclude attribute dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689566/how-to-add-xmlinclude-attribute-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice reusable method:

```
string sSerialData = "";

SerializeQueueType<BaseClassType>(oDerivedObject, out sSerialData)


private bool SerializeDerivedObject<T>(T oDerivedObject, out string sOutput)
{
    bool bReturn = false;

    sOutput = "";

    try
    {

        Type[] arrTypes = new Type[1];
        arrTypes[0] = oDerivedObject.GetType();

        XmlSerializer xmlSerl = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), arrTypes); 
        System.IO.MemoryStream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        xmlSerl.Serialize(memStream, oDerivedObject); 

        memStream.Position = 0;

        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(memStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            sOutput = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        bReturn = true;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //_log.Error(ex);
    }


    return bReturn;

}
```