# Adding XmlIncludeAttribute programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I'm trying to add some hints to the XmlSerializor so it can serialize/deserialize interfaces. I can't add the [XmlIncludeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx) as a decoration on the class, in stead I want to pass in serialization overrides to the XmlSerializor:

```
var _xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Model.ISession), SerializationOverrides());
```

The `SerializationOverrides()` looks like this:

```
private static XmlAttributeOverrides SerializationOverrides()
{
    var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

    overrides.Add(typeof(Model.ISession), XmlInclude(typeof(Model.Session)));

    return overrides;
}
```

So far, so good. The `XmlInclude(...)` method creates a new [XmlAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.aspx) object, but I can't figure out how to add the [XmlIncludeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx) attribute.

```
private static XmlAttributes XmlInclude(Type type)
{
    var attrs = new XmlAttributes();

    attrs....Add(new XmlIncludeAttribute(type)); // Add how?????

    return attrs;
}
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XmlSerializer constructor can accept an array of "extra types", like this:

```
var _xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Model.ISession), 
    SerializationOverrides(), new Type[] { typeof(Model.Session), 
    new XmlRootAttribute("Session"), "");
```

Doing that as well as adding additional XmlElements to the overrides seems to be doing the trick:

```
private static XmlAttributeOverrides SerializationOverrides()
{
    var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

    overrides.Add(typeof(Model.ISession), XmlInclude("Session", typeof(Model.Session)));

    return overrides;
}

private static XmlAttributes XmlInclude(string name, Type type)
{
    var attrs = new XmlAttributes();
    attrs.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute(name, type));
    return attrs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From best of my knowledge, **you can't**
You have to provide attributes at compile time.
Attributes are static data and your best bet would probably be using [TypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.aspx). (Look at `TypeDescriptor.CreateProperty`)
Probably you can try to create a derived class with necessary attributes?

**EDIT. Looks like you can!**

See [Marc Gravell answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2689660/1792936)

example:

```
 var aor = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        var Attribs = new XmlAttributes();
        Attribs.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute("Session", typeof(Model.Session)));
        aor.Add(typeof(type), "Models", listAttribs);

        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(type), aor);
```