# Serializing List of base object types using XmlMessageFormatter

Tags: xml-serialization, msmq, message-queue

I have an object like so:

```
public class Intent
{
    public List<Entity> Updates { get; set; }
}
```

Which I wish to serialize into XML for passing as a message using MSMQ. The list of type Entity can contain any number of instances of classes that inherit from Entity. For example, there may be:

```
public Person : Entity { /* ... */ }
public Vehicle : Entity { /* ... */ }
```

I'm using XmlMessageFormatter, which so far I have defined as:

```
XmlMessageFormatter _formatter =
        new XmlMessageFormatter(new[] { typeof(T) });
```

Where T in this instance is Intent (as above).

Trouble is, when the code actually attempts to serialize the following exception occurs:

```
The type CoreApi.Domain.Person was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.
```

I believe this is because I need to tell the serializer somehow of the fact that Person is a child class of entity.

I've seen solutions that basically entail adorning Entity with multiple XmlInclude decorations, which in my scenario is unworkable as the list of inheritors of Entity is large and could grow - I don't want to constantly update this list as new inheritors are added.

I've seen other solutions that use XmlSerializer, passing in a list of known types, the trouble with this is that I somehow need to replace XmlMessageSerialiser with the XmlSerialiser instance which isn't compatible.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into a similar problem

Comment: I evantually switched to WCF for MSMQ and used the System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownType attribute on the service contract, perhaps for raw MSMQ this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689566/how-to-add-xmlinclude-attribute-dynamically