# PropertyInfo on a dynamic object is System.Object is not what is wanted

Tags: c#, dynamic, propertyinfo

I create a dynamic type at run-time (please see how here: [Serialize/Deserialize a dynamic object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559897/serialize-deserialize-a-dynamic-object)) and use that type to create a dynamic member in another class.

```
    public class SomeClass
    {
        private dynamic _AnimalType = CreateAnimal<Animal>("Dog");
        public dynamic AnimalType { get { return _AnimalType; } }

        static internal PropertyInfo[] Sprops = typeof(SomeClass).GetProperties();
        static public PropertyInfo[] getPropertyInfos() { get { return Sprops; } }
    }
```

However, when the following is called:

```
        PropertyInfo[] Sprops = typeof(SomeClass).GetProperties();
```

Sprops contains one PropertyInfo (`System.Object`), which is 'exptected' but not what is 'wanted'.  I would like to get the Type that AnimalType is currently (`Animal`, or more specifically `Dog`).  Is there any way to accomplish this?  I do not want to have to create an instance of this class and then call some "SetInternalProperties" method.  The idea is to have the properties readily available as a static.

Comment: *I get a System.Object property* what does that mean? Where do you get `System.Object` ? Please clarify.

Comment: Clarified above: Sprops contains one PropertyInfo ('System.Object')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `PropertyInfo` isn't capable of getting the runtime type of the field. All it does is it gets you the type of the property what is declared.

> So it should be something `dynamic` isn't it? Why did you get
>   `System.Object` ?

Well, dynamic is just `System.Object` under the covers decorated with [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.dynamicattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That's why you just see `System.Object`. There is no way to get the runtime information(without the instance).

*Is there any way to accomplish this?* : If you can explain what you're trying to achieve you may get better answer.

If you have the instance of `SomeClass` you can find what is the runtime type.

```
SomeClass instance = new SomeClass();// get instance somehow
PropertyInfo pi = ...;//Get the property info
Type dynamicType = pi.GetValue(instance).GetType();
```

Comment: Yes, makes total sense what you said, and I know exactly why I am getting System.Object instead of the type I want.  Maybe I do have to go about this in a different way.  Ive clarified a bit more.  Hope it helps explain what Im trying to do.

Comment: @Tizz I updated my answer to show how to get that information from instance of `SomeClass`. Without instance, you can't find it for obvious reasons(because you can store whatever at runtime in separate instances).

Comment: Thank you, that helps. The current code uses PropertyInfo[] to do a bunch of things, and I am trying to fit my solution into it.  I like that I can get the dynamic Type, but I really need a PropertyInfo of that type.  Can you continue to help further?

Comment: `PropertyInfo` is a abstract class, which doesn't have any public implementation. So you can't create instance yourself. To get a instance of `PropertyInfo` with type that doesn't exist is very hard. If your code is very much coupled with `PropertyInfo` you need to decouple it. May be an interface, or `MyCustomPropertyInfo` class with property named `PropertyType` can help. with that you can return the dynamic property from your implementation. I hope this helps.

Comment: I knew there was no answer, just wanted another way to look at it and you did help.  I ended up changing the 'Implemented code' to handle a dynamic case.  And using the `PropertyType` as you showed above was key in implementing that.  Thanks!