# Deserialize XML with multiple types

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, xsi

I'm trying to deserialize XML where some same name tags have different xsi types:

```
<user-defined-data-row>
  <field name="entity">
    <field-value xsi:type="field-text-valueType">
      <value>Test</value>
    </field-value>
  </field>
  <field name="expiry_date">
    <field-value xsi:type="field-date-valueType">
      <value>2001-10-07</value>
    </field-value>
  </field>
</user-defined-data-row>
```

This is easily achieved by deserializing the xml into this model:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "field-value", Namespace = "http://www.crsoftwareinc.com/xml/ns/titanium/common/v1_0")]
[XmlType("field-text-valueType")]
public class Fieldvalue
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "value", Namespace = "http://www.crsoftwareinc.com/xml/ns/titanium/common/v1_0")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The only thing that differs are the types in the XML:

**field-text-valueType**

**field-date-valueType**

How can I make the C# class interpret both types using something like

```
[XmlType("field-text-valueType")]
```

EDIT: deserializing not serializing

Comment: Do you mean **de**serializing?

Comment: The type attribute indicates the class inherits a base class where field-value is the base class name and field-text-valueType is the sub class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `xsi:type` attributes you are seeing in your XML are standard W3C XML Schema attributes that allow an element to explicitly specify its type; for details see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_type).  As explained in [*Xsi:type Attribute Binding Support*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca1ks327.aspx), `XmlSerializer` supports this mechanism for deserialization of polymorphic types, specifically by use of [`XmlIncludeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx).

First, define an abstract base class `FieldValue` as follows:

```
public static class XmlNamespaces
{
    public const string Crsoftwareinc = "http://www.crsoftwareinc.com/xml/ns/titanium/common/v1_0";
}

[XmlRoot("field-value", Namespace = XmlNamespaces.Crsoftwareinc)]
[XmlType("field-value", Namespace = XmlNamespaces.Crsoftwareinc)]
[XmlInclude(typeof(TextFieldValue)), 
XmlInclude(typeof(DateFieldValue))]
public abstract partial class FieldValue
{
    // It's not necessary to have this in the base class but I usually find it convenient.
    public abstract object GetValue();
}
```

Next, for each possible `xsi:type="XXX"` value, define a derived type of `FieldValue` whose [`XmlTypeAttribute.TypeName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute.typename.aspx) matches the `xsi:type` value.  Decorate the base class with `[XmlInclude(typeof(TDerivedFieldValue))]` attributes for each (already shown above):

```
[XmlRoot("field-text-valueType", Namespace = XmlNamespaces.Crsoftwareinc)]
[XmlType("field-text-valueType", Namespace = XmlNamespaces.Crsoftwareinc)]
public class TextFieldValue : FieldValue
{
    [XmlElement("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public override object GetValue() { return Value; }
}

[XmlRoot("field-date-valueType", Namespace = XmlNamespaces.Crsoftwareinc)]
[XmlType("field-date-valueType", Namespace = XmlNamespaces.Crsoftwareinc)]
public class DateFieldValue : FieldValue
{
    [XmlElement("value", DataType = "date")]
    public DateTime Value { get; set; }

    public override object GetValue() { return Value; }
}
```

Then define the containing type corresponding to `<field>` and other, higher elements as follows:

```
[XmlRoot("field", Namespace = XmlNamespaces.Crsoftwareinc)]
[XmlType("field", Namespace = XmlNamespaces.Crsoftwareinc)]
public class Field
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("field-value")]
    public FieldValue FieldValue { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("user-defined-data-row", Namespace = XmlNamespaces.Crsoftwareinc)]
[XmlType("user-defined-data-row", Namespace = XmlNamespaces.Crsoftwareinc)]
public class UserDefinedDataRow
{
    [XmlElement("field")]
    public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
}

// The XML for the root object is not shown so this is just a stub
[XmlRoot("root", Namespace = XmlNamespaces.Crsoftwareinc)]
[XmlType("root", Namespace = XmlNamespaces.Crsoftwareinc)]
public class RootObject
{
    [XmlElement("user-defined-data-row")]
    public List<UserDefinedDataRow> Rows { get; set; }
}
```

Notes:

- If the base class `FieldValue` has a namespace specified in via [`XmlTypeAttribute.Namespace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute.namespace.aspx), then the derived classes must also, or else an error will get thrown by `XmlSerializer`.

  Once an `[XmlType]` namespace is defined, it automatically applies to all serialized properties, so it isn't necessary to specify the same namespace via `[XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.crsoftwareinc.com/xml/ns/titanium/common/v1_0")]` attributes.
- I got tired of repeatedly typing the namespace `"http://www.crsoftwareinc.com/xml/ns/titanium/common/v1_0"` and so I extracted it into a constant.
- Other derived types of `FieldType` can be added easily, e.g.:

  ```
  [XmlRoot("field-decimal-valueType", Namespace = XmlNamespaces.Crsoftwareinc)]
  [XmlType("field-decimal-valueType", Namespace = XmlNamespaces.Crsoftwareinc)]
  public class DecimalFieldValue : FieldValue
  {
      [XmlElement("value")]
      public decimal Value { get; set; }

      public override object GetValue() { return Value; }
  }

  [XmlInclude(typeof(DecimalFieldValue))]
  public abstract partial class FieldValue { }
  ```

  Don't forget to add `[XmlInclude(typeof(DecimalFieldValue))]` when doing so.
- If you have been given an XSD for the XML you are trying to deserialize that specifies the possible types of `<field-value>` via e.g. an [`<xsd:extension>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256161.aspx) element as shown in [*Generating XML Documents from XML Schemas: Abstract Types*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx#code-snippet-13), then [`xsd.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe) will generate classes that include an appropriate type hierarchy.  But if you only have the XML, then `xsd.exe` and [**Paste XML as Classes**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/generating-data-type-classes-from-xml) will *not* generate a correct type hierarchy using whatever `xsi:type` attributes are present.

  For more about this limitation see *[xsi:type attribute messing up C# XML deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36361653/3744182)*.
- Your XML is not well-formed because it omits a declaration for the `xsi:` namespace.  Also, a default namespace `xmlns="http://www.crsoftwareinc.com/xml/ns/titanium/common/v1_0"` is not defined so none of the elements are actually in this namespace.  Thus I assume your XML is a fragment of some larger document that is valid, e.g.

  ```
  <root 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns="http://www.crsoftwareinc.com/xml/ns/titanium/common/v1_0">
    <user-defined-data-row>
        <!-- Remainder as shown in the question -->
    </user-defined-data-row>
  </root>
  ```

Sample working .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZCfMXZ).