# How to parse xml to an object with a xsi:type in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, parsing, xsi

At this moment I'm struggling to deserialize an XML response from BRO ( part of the Dutch government). They have a public API that can be used to get groundwater levels and details.
This is the response( [url](https://publiek.broservices.nl/gm/gld/v1/objects/GLD000000000081?observationPeriodBeginDate=2022-01-16&observationPeriodEndDate=2022-05-16) ).

If I change this part `xsi:type="ns11:GLD_O_DPType"` with string.replace the XML can be parsed.

From:
`<ns11:GLD_O xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns11:GLD_O_DPType" gml:id="BRO_0002">`

To:
`<ns11:GLD_O xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" gml:id="BRO_0002">`

The XML container class is created true my IDE Visual Studio 2022 via Edit > paste Special > Paste XML As Classes. And this is the [generated class](https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/yofifirotu.csharp)

The following code is used to deserialize the XML:

```
public static T ParseXML<T>(this string @this) where T : class
        {
            if(@this == null) { return null; }
            var reader = XmlReader.Create(@this.Trim().ToStream(), new XmlReaderSettings() { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document });
            return new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(reader) as T;
        }

// In my mainclass
var parsedResult = ParseHelpers.ParseXML<dispatchDataResponse>(result);
```

In my mainclass, result is a type of string from the response body of the request (first link)

In short, how can I deserialize the object with the attribute xmlns:xsi

Comment: The type attribute means you have an inherited class.  You need to use XmlInclude : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute?force_isolation=true&view=net-6.0.  You also have xsi so the namespace need to be set.

Comment: *Paste XML As Classes* will not correctly interpret `xsi:type` attributes, which are used to indicate polymorphic subtype.  However, if you have an **XSD schema** for your XML file, you can generate correct classes using xsd.exe.  Since the XML is from an official government source I'd be willing to bet there is a corresponding XSD, so you should get it and use it for your code generation.  For details of why an XSD is preferable see [xsi:type attribute messing up C# XML deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36365689/3744182).

Comment: But beyond pointing you to [xsi:type attribute messing up C# XML deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36365689/3744182) we probably need to see a [mcve] to help you.  See: [ask].

Answer (score 0):

In order for the XML Serializer to recognize the type, you need to change the generated code in line 111 from:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
// The following line needs to be changed
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.broservices.nl/xsd/dsgld/1.0")]
public partial class dispatchDataResponseDispatchDocumentGLD_O
{

    private string broIdField;
```

to

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
// This asserts that the type name is recognized
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(TypeName = "GLD_O_DPType", Namespace = "http://www.broservices.nl/xsd/dsgld/1.0")]
public partial class dispatchDataResponseDispatchDocumentGLD_O
{

    private string broIdField;
```