# XML Deserialization with MEF objects as XmlIncludes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, mef

I use XML for my configuration files and currently I deserialize into objects or lists of objects directly.  I also use Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) to make extensions to our application platform but I haven't found a way to tie the two together.

For instance if I wanted to add a new object to this base class using XMLInclude:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(SubObject1))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(SubObject2))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(SubObject3))]
//New XmlInclude Types based on plugins?
[XmlType("SupportedObject")]
public class SupportedObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

with XML:

```
<SupportedObjects>
  <SupportedObject xsi:type="SubObject1">
      <Name>MainSub1</Name>
      <SubObject1Param>FooBar</SubObject1Param>
  </SupportedObject>

  <!-- MEF Plugin Object -->
  <SupportedObject xsi:type="MefObject1">
      <Name>MainSub1</Name>
      <MefParam1>something new</MefParam1>
  </SupportedObject>
</SupportedObjects>
```

The first object would load fine because it is defined using the XmlInclude but how do I define an extension that is compiled in a dll and loaded as a lazy list object with contract to be included as a supported object xmlinclude as well?  I'm quite vexed.

Comment: Does this answer your question?  [How to add XmlInclude attribute dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2689566/3744182)

Comment: So the process would be to load the extensions then add the xml include attribute dynamically, then perform the xml deserialization?

Comment: Yes.  You would also need to cache the `XmlSerializer` statically as explained in [Memory Leak using StreamReader and XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23897145/3744182).