# Dynamically create, and use, an enumeration type

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, enums

I have searched google and have gotten bits and pieces of this puzzle I am trying to create, yet there are still missing pieces that I cannot figure out:

I am trying to create, and fully use, a dynamic Enumeration Type.

This is what I have and is the basis for this discussion. It is the NON dynamic way of doing things. This is what I am trying to mimic:

```
// 1) Create the enum and classes
public enum MyAnimals { Cat, Dog, Pig };

public abstract class Animal { internal MyAnimals _myType; 
                               public MyAnimals myType {get{return _myType;}} }
public class Cat : Animal { public Cat(){_myType = MyAnimals.Cat;} }
public class Dog : Animal { public Dog(){_myType = MyAnimals.Dog;} }
public class Pig : Animal { public Pig(){_myType = MyAnimals.Pig;} }

// 2) Instantiate a class and a variable using the enum
Dog aDog = new Dog(); // aDog.myType is 'Dog'
MyAnimals theAnimal; // Will default to 'Cat'

// 3) Change the variable to another enum
aDog.myType = MyAnimals.Cat; // Error, cant change Type!  Good!
theAnimal = MyAnimals.Pig;

// 4) Use the variable in a method call
public void Method( MyAnimals animal ) { ... }

Method( aDog.myType );
Method( theAnimal );
```

and here is how I do this dynamically.  I can currently get to step 3, but even then it is ugly code.  Can anyone get #4 for me, or help me with this whole situation?

```
// 1) Create the enum  and classes
public static Type MyAnimals;

public static dynamic getAnimal(string name)
{
    dynamic theAnimal = Activator.CreateInstance(MyAnimals); // Will default to 'Cat'
    FieldInfo fi = MyAnimals.GetField(name);
    int iEnum = (int)fi.GetValue(MyAnimals);
    return Enum.ToObject(MyAnimals, iEnum);
}
public abstract class Animal { internal dynamic _myType; 
                               public dynamic myType { get { return _myType; } } }
public class Cat : Animal { public Cat() { _myType = getAnimal("Cat"); } }
public class Dog : Animal { public Dog() { _myType = getAnimal("Dog"); } }
public class Pig : Animal { public Pig() { _myType = getAnimal("Pig"); } }

// Get the current application domain for the current thread.
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;

// Create a dynamic assembly in the current application domain
AssemblyName aName = new AssemblyName("TempAssembly");
AssemblyBuilder ab = currentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(aName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);

ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(aName.Name);

EnumBuilder eb = mb.DefineEnum("MyAnimalType", TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(int));

var types = new List<Type>();
int Count = 0;
foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    types.AddRange(assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Animal))));

foreach (var type in types)
    eb.DefineLiteral(type.Name, Count++);

// Create the type
MyAnimals = eb.CreateType();

// 2) Instantiate a variable using the enum
Cat c = new Cat();
dynamic theAnimal = getAnimal("Pig");

// 3) Change the vairable to another enum
c.myType = getAnimal("Dog"); // Error, again, good
theAnimal = getAnimal("Dog");

// 4) Use the variable in a method call
public void Method( MyAnimals animal ) // Compile error: 'MyAnimals' is a field but used like a type.
```

Comment: public void Method(typeof(MyAnimals) animal) maybe?

Comment: You seem to have skipped from code using CodeDom etc, to trying to declare a method *directly in your source code*. If you're trying to build a method, you need to do that dynamically too. It's very hard to understand what you're really trying to achieve here - can you give more context? How do you expect to use the dynamically-generated type afterwards?

Comment: or MyAnimals.GetType()

Comment: Out of interest _why_ would you want to do this?

Comment: This is a continuation of my other question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999681/how-can-i-know-the-classes-that-extend-my-base-class-at-runtime - I want to create an enum based on the class extentions, without having to maintain an enum (remembering to adding to it everytime I want another 'animal')

Comment: @Jon Skeet I want to use it as close to a regular enum as possible.  I would like to index it, serialize it, switch on it, etc.

Comment: @Tizz: Well you can't do that within the code that you're writing, if the enum doesn't exist yet. How would the compiler know which switch cases were valid? You could do that with code that you write which refers to the dynamically generated code, but that's completely different. We still don't really have much context here...

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right, I cannot switch, bad example. What I really want to display a list of Animal types they can create, then display a tree view of all the animals, sorted by type (will add pics to the original post) Also not sure I have much more context to provide other than what I stated. I dont want to maintain an enum, its a pain to have to update it everytime I want to extend my base class, or decide that I want to change the name of the extended classes, etc.  Is there a better/easier solution to this than what I am trying to do?

Comment: It's unclear why you don't just need a `List<T>` of some description. Have your `MyAnimal` class load a set of its possible values, and expose that either as a list, or something similar, and you're away. No need for CodeDom at all.

Comment: Interesting idea. List<T> is not an enum though.  I am trying to use another set of helper classes (ones I cannot touch) that will generate my tree and dropdowns based on the type and properties on the type.  One check is, if .IsEnum, then create a dropdown. (I also updated the code a bit)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure that this is such a good idea, but if this architecture is finalized, here's what you can do.

1. Once your run time type has been created, you can pass it to any of the static methods defined for the [`Enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Enum_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, including

   1. [`Enum.GetNames(runtmeType)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - gets an array of the defined names of your enum.
   2. [`Enum.GetValues(runtimeType)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - gets an array of the defined member values of your enum.
   3. [`Enum.Parse(runtmeType, string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - converts the string representation of the name or value of an enum of the specified type to the equivalent member of the type.
   4. [`Enum.ToObject(runtmeType, /*some integer type*/)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2wdkedz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - converts an integer to the equivalent enumeration member.
2. All members of enumerations inherit from the [`Enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Enum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, so if you want to write code in advance to deal with enums of your run-time type, you can write nonspecific methods that take an `Enum` as an argument.  (Of course, you lose some compile-time type checking if you do this.)  For instance, you can do `Enum myEnum = Enum.Parse(myAnimalType, "Pig")`, and then pass the returned `myEnum` to any method you want to write for it.  And an `Enum` itself has a few useful instance methods, e.g. [methods to convert it to various types of integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340080%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
3. Next, if you happen to have a generic method that takes an enum as one of its input arguments, you can invoke it with [`MakeGenericMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  For instance, if you have the following method and class:

   ```
   public static class EnumHelper
   {
       public static ulong ToUInt64<TEnum>(TEnum value) where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IComparable, IFormattable
       {
           // Silently convert the value to UInt64 from the other base 
           // types for enum without throwing an exception.
           // This is need since the Convert functions do overflow checks.
           TypeCode typeCode = value.GetTypeCode();
           ulong result;

           switch (typeCode)
           {
               case TypeCode.SByte:
               case TypeCode.Int16:
               case TypeCode.Int32:
               case TypeCode.Int64:
                   unchecked
                   {
                       result = (UInt64)value.ToInt64(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                   }
                   break;

               case TypeCode.Byte:
               case TypeCode.UInt16:
               case TypeCode.UInt32:
               case TypeCode.UInt64:
               case TypeCode.Boolean:
               case TypeCode.Char:
                   unchecked
                   {
                       result = value.ToUInt64(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                   }
                   break;

               default:
                   throw new InvalidOperationException();
           }
           return result;
       }
   }
   ```

   you can call it with

   ```
   MethodInfo method = typeof(EnumHelper).GetMethod("ToUInt64");
   MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(myEnum.GetType());
   UInt64 myValue = (UInt64)generic.Invoke(null, new object [] { myEnum } );
   ```
4. Similarly, you can create instances of generic classes based on your run time type with [`MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  For instance, a dictionary of enums to strings would look like this:

   ```
   Type dictType = typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(runtimeType, typeof(string));
   var dict = Activator.CreateInstance(dictType);
   ```
5. You can combine techniques 3 and 4 to write most of your code in advance.  Say you know you are going to create a run-time type of animals, for which you want to perform certain actions.  You can create a non-generic top level interface that returns `Enum` instances:

   ```
   public interface IEnumProcessor 
   {
        IList<string> GetAllValues();

        bool ProcessInput(string userValue);

        Enum GetCurrentValue();
   }
   ```

   then refine that with a generic interface:

   ```
   public interface IEnumProcessor<TEnum> : IEnumProcessor where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IComparable, IFormattable

        new TEnum GetCurrentValue();

        void AddSelectedValue(TEnum value);
   }
   ```

   and finally create a generic class with the actual code:

   ```
   public class EnumProcessor<T> where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IComparable, IFormattable
   {

   }
   ```

   You can create instances of this processor with `MakeGenericType`, call methods with `MakeGenericMethod`, then pass it to other code you write as an IEnumProcessor if that code does not need to know the specific type of enum.

Finally, note that, since the underlying type of an enum can be an s/byte, u/short, u/int or u/long, with this architecture *you will never be able to have more than 64 instances of your run time type*.  If you want more you need a different architecture, at the minimum defining your enum as a bit field with the [`[Flags]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute and then defining your enum values as composites, which might have unforeseen (by me) consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Step 3 and 4 can be done using the Enum.Parse() method:

```
var theAnimal = Enum.Parse(typeof(MyAnimals), "Pig");
```

No Dynamics necessary.

Comment: Not sure what the question is about #4?

Comment: This appears to be a comment for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25256727/215552), not an actual answer...