# Castle Windsor: Conditional registration of open generic types

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, open-generics

I have the following:

```
class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
interface ISuperRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
class SuperRepository<T> : ISuperRepository<T>
interface ISuperType
```

I want conditional registration in **Castle Windsor DI** for `IRepository<T>`, if `T` is `ISuperType`, then provide `ISuperRepository<T>`. Else, provide `IRepository<T>.`

So for example, if `A : ISuperType`, then I want `Resolve<IRepository<A>>` to provide `SuperRepository<A>`, and `Resolve<IRepository<B>>` to provide `Repository<B>`.

How can I achive that?

Comment: Every layer of indirection (aka Conditional) is solved by another layer of abstraction - FactoryProvider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Castle Windsor` doesn't support such a thing, however you can achieve it with a simple helper method:

```
public static void RegisterAccordingToISuperType<T>(this IWindsorContainer container)
{
    if (typeof (T).GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof (ISuperType)))
        container.Register(Component.For<IRepository<T>>()
                                    .ImplementedBy<SuperRepository<T>>());
    else
        container.Register(Component.For<IRepository<T>>()
                                    .ImplementedBy<Repository<T>>());
}
```

Then the registration:

```
container.RegisterAccordingToISuperType<SuperType>();
container.RegisterAccordingToISuperType<int>();
```

And the resolve will:

```
var super = container.Resolve<IRepository<SuperType>>();
var intRepo = container.Resolve<IRepository<int>>();
```

Another option is to the extra parameter in `Component.For`. Then gets all type which inherite form the Type([For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857705/get-all-derived-types-of-a-type)) and register them.

```
private static void Register(...)
{
    foreach (var type in GetInheriteTypes())
    {          
        container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IRepository<>),type)
                                    .ImplementedBy(typeof(SuperRepository<>)));
    }
    container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IRepository<>))
                                .ImplementedBy(typeof(Repository<>)));
}

private static IEnumerable<Type> GetInheriteTypes()
{
    var listOfBs = (from domainAssembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                    from assemblyType in domainAssembly.GetTypes()
                    where assemblyType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ISuperType))
                    select assemblyType).ToArray();
    return listOfBs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I have many classes that implement ISuperType so I like the second approach, but it doesn't seem work - the resolved type is always SuperRepository<T> and not Repository<T>.

Comment: @Rita How your `Resolve` looks? If the `Resolve` looks like my example it should be work(It worked in my computer)

Comment: @Rita one more thing, verify that you didn't register something before the foreach, if you did so, you have to use the `Default()` extension method.

Comment: I couldn't get that to work. Component.For(typeof(IRepository<>),type) was completely ignoring the type. I ended up registering with MakeGenericType. I'd appreciate if you can tell me what the problem is. Anyway, this is the code and it works for me:
            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                container.Register(Component.For(typeof (IRepository<>).MakeGenericType(type))
                                            .ImplementedBy(typeof (SuperRepository<>).MakeGenericType(type)));
            }

Comment: I forgot to mention, I also need registration of Component.For(typeof(ISuperRepository<>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(SuperRepository<>).

Answer (score -1):

You can restrict what types a generic is used for with the "where T: typename" syntax, where "typename" refers to a type the specified type 'T' must inherit (or implement). In your case "where T: ISuperType" would match the specific types, and a version without the restriction should match all the rest.

ref. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx

If it can't be done at compile-time, it can always be done at runtime (with f.ex. 'is').

Comment: This is not the problem I'm having. I'm looking for a way to do a conditional registration in Castle Windsor DI.

Comment: Provided "registration" means "running code" (while I have a cursory understanding of the subject, I've never delved deeper into it), what would be preventing from testing if T is of type ISuperType? I'm here assuming there's a small "factory" for these repository objects, so it can select the right one.

Comment: @tamlin You might want to learn [what DI is in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and what [Castle Windsor](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/README.md) is in particular.