# Find if interface is used in my project C#

Tags: c#, .net

I need to find if specific interface is used in project, I just found something like

```
Type IType = Type.GetType("iInterfaceName"); // I want to look in whole project, not in one file
if (IType == null)
{  
   Text = "Interface Not Exist";
}
else
{
    Text = "Interface Exist";
}
```

I am not sure if this is correct but this is the latest thing I found and in doesn't work,
any help greatly appreciated...

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface-with-c-sharp-3-5 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927861/how-to-find-what-classes-implements-an-interface-net

Comment: oops, didn't see it... so sorry

Answer (score 1):

Use `Assembly.Load` before you go for `GetType` as follows:

```
Assembly.Load("YourProjectName")
        .GetType("iInterfaceName");
```

Comment: 1) What error are you getting? 2) Why are you using .NET 2.0?

Comment: Hold on. Are you looking for the Interface itself, or classes that implement that interface?

Comment: Are you sure it's in that project, that it's spelled correctly, and that you've picked the correct project name?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have the following interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
}
```

You can find out if there's any type implementing it this way:

```
var isImplemented = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().
                             GetTypes().
                             Any(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (IFoo)));
```

To use the above, add to your using directives:

```
using System.Linq;
```

For .NET 2.0:

```
var isImplemented = false;
foreach (var t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
{
    if (!t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (IFoo))) continue;
    isImplemented = true;
    break;
}
//Operate
```

Comment: I am using .net 2.0, don't have System.linq

Comment: it gives me IFoo(where iFoo is my interface name) can not be found error

Comment: and it makes sense because I don't know if this interface is used in my application, I need to find it on runtime

Comment: @Stanislav You need to post more information about your error. Compile time, run-time? Update your post.

Comment: sorry, Error 1 The type or namespace name 'IFoo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Stanislav C# is case-sensitive. `iFoo` and `IFoo` are not the same.

Comment: alright fixed that but now if statement gives an error: Error SA1503: The body of the if statement must be wrapped in opening and closing curly brackets.

Comment: @Stanislav Sorry but I can't help you with that. You have a perfectly working piece of code and you can adapt it to your needs. Please try to do that. Probably you erased a closing curly bracket and you need to put it back.

Comment: thanks for help, I don't see any problem with this if statement either, but it gives me an error for no reason...