# Difference between AppDomain.GetAssemblies and BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies

Tags: assemblies, buildmanager

Just wanted to know if there is any difference between the two, in the context of a fully trust asp.net mvc 2 application.

Comment: @starblue: care to explain the vote down?

Comment: Thanks for asking this.  I didn't know BuildManager existed, which just totally saved me.  (Because of the behavior Levi described)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The .NET Framework defers loading assemblies into the current AppDomain until they're needed.  For example, if you call into a third-party library only from `SomeMethod()`, the third-party DLL normally won't be loaded until the first time `SomeMethod()` runs.

`AppDomain.GetAssemblies()` gives you all assemblies which have already been loaded into the current AppDomain.  `BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()` (This method is only available in the **.Net Framework** `System.Web.dll`) returns a list of all assemblies referenced from Web.config and elsewhere, and it loads those assemblies into the current AppDomain.

Here's a worked-out example of the above.

1. `SomeMethod()` hasn't yet run.
2. Call `AppDomain.GetAssemblies()`, returns a set that does not include ThirdParty.dll.
3. Call `SomeMethod()`.
4. Call `AppDomain.GetAssemblies()`, returns a set that includes ThirdParty.dll.

In this example, the CLR defers loading ThirdParty.dll into the current AppDomain until it's absolutely necessary.  And since it's necessary for the execution of `SomeMethod()`, that's when it gets loaded.

Alternatively:

1. `SomeMethod()` hasn't yet run.
2. Call `AppDomain.GetAssemblies()`, returns a set that does not include ThirdParty.dll.
3. Call `BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()`, returns a set that includes ThirdParty.dll.
4. Call `AppDomain.GetAssemblies()`, returns a set that includes ThirdParty.dll.

Here, even though you never called `SomeMethod()`, the call to `BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()` loaded the third-party library into the current AppDomain on your behalf.

Of course, this is all subject to certain optimizations, etc., but the general idea holds.

Comment: So the only way to get a hold of BuildManager is by referencing System.Web.dll? Sounds a bit weird.

Comment: @Ted What's wrong with this?  I simplified quite a bit in my answer above, but the concept of BuildManager only really makes sense inside an ASP.NET application.

Comment: yes, referencing System.Web.dll and using BuildManager will throw an exception if its not an ASP.NET project. In a WinForms you cant do this.

Comment: Why would you want / need to reference BuildManager outside of ASP.NET?  BuildManager is specifically designed to interface with the ASP.NET compilation system, so it doesn't make sense to reference this type from a WinForms application.  Consider opening a new SO question with the exact problem you're trying to solve, as more than likely there's a supported way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: @Levi, probably because he wants to get all of the referenced assemblies and the BuildManager has a method for getting all of the referenced assemblies.

Comment: It's worth noting that this answer is now 11 years old and `BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()` doesn't exist **at all** in .Net Core or .Net 5.0.