# Unity IOC sometimes cant resolve dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I am having a weird problem using Unity as an IOC container and im out of ideas of what could cause it. I have a service dependency in my webapi controller but it randomly fails to resolve this dependency. Sometimes i have to start my application 3 or 4 times and then it suddenly works again.

The error I am getting is:

> Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Base.WebApi.Controllers.ApiUsersController", name = "(none)". Exception occurred while: while resolving. Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type IApiUserService does not have an accessible constructor. ----------------------------------------------- At the time of the exception, the container was: Resolving Base.WebApi.Controllers.ApiUsersController,(none) Resolving parameter "apiUserService" of constructor Base.WebApi.Controllers.ApiUsersController(Base.BLL.Services.User.IApiUserService apiUserService) Resolving Base.BLL.Services.User.IApiUserService,(none)

For initializing and registering my types in unity i use the following:

```cs
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    var myAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a => a.FullName.StartsWith("Base") && !a.FullName.StartsWith("Base.WebApi")).ToArray();

    container.RegisterType(typeof(Startup));

    container.RegisterTypes(
            UnityHelpers.GetTypesWithCustomAttribute<UnityIoCSingletonLifetimedAttribute>(myAssemblies),
            WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
            WithName.Default,
            WithLifetime.ContainerControlled,
            null
        ).RegisterTypes(
                UnityHelpers.GetTypesWithCustomAttribute<UnityIoCTransientLifetimedAttribute>(myAssemblies),
                WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
                WithName.Default,
                WithLifetime.Transient);

}
```

As you can see i am using singletone and transient named attributes to define the way my dependencies should be resolved.

My controller looks like this:

```cs
public class ApiUsersController : ODataController
{

    private readonly IApiUserService _apiUserService;

    public ApiUsersController(IApiUserService apiUserService)
    {
        _apiUserService = apiUserService;
    }

    public IQueryable<ApiUserEntity> Get()
    {
        return this._apiUserService.GetUsers();
    }
}
```

as you can see it has a dependency on user service which looks like this:

```cs
[UnityIoCTransientLifetimed]
public class ApiUserService : BaseService, IApiUserService
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository; 

    public ApiUserService(IUserRepository userRepository, IUnitOfWork uow) : base(uow)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }
 }
```

The api user repository looks like this:

```cs
[UnityIoCTransientLifetimed]
public class UserRepository :  GenericRepository<ApiUserEntity>, IUserRepository
{
    public UserRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IDomainContext context) : base(unitOfWork, context)
    {

    }
```

Extending the following GenericRepository:

```cs
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly BaseContext Context;

    public GenericRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IBaseContext context)
    {
        // register this repository with the unit of work.
        unitOfWork.Register(this);

        Context = (BaseContext)context;
    }
```

With my unit of work that looks like this:

```cs
[UnityIoCSingletonLifetimed]
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, IRepository> _repositories;

    // unit of work class is responsible for creating the repository and then dispossing it when no longer needed.
    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _repositories = new Dictionary<string, IRepository>();
    }
 }
```

However it sometimes works and sometimes it doesnt and i cant figure out why or where to look.

Comment: Does it work if you register the types explicitly instead of using registration by convention?

Comment: Possibly the `IApiUserService` isn't registered before the `ApiUsersController`, which means that it doesn't have a type to inject into that constructor.

Comment: btw, are you able to reproduce the issue in debug? If you are, can you check what is returned by `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`? I suspect the explanation might be that the assembly containing `ApiUserService` is not loaded yet.

Comment: @RonBeyer, the registration order doesn't matter, as long as everything is registered before you try to resolve

Comment: I just tried to register them explicitely and it has not crashed once since. restarted about 5/6 times. It seems to be in the GetAssemblies part indeed.

Comment: Ok guys it is indeed in the getassemblies. I used registration by convention again and sometimes it does not load the Base.BLL assembly (the one where apiuserservice is located) and sometimes it does. How can that be?

Comment: So sometimes this: http://i.imgur.com/AaRbdo3.png (all good)
and sometimes this: http://i.imgur.com/W9VLw7l.png (missing base.BLL )

Comment: Just came accross this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477787/difference-between-appdomain-getassemblies-and-buildmanager-getreferencedassembli which tells me getassemblies only loads all assemblies when its needed.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved it thanks to some suggestions. Looking at the documentation for

```cs
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
```

it says the following:
Gets the assemblies that have been loaded into the execution **context** of this application domain.

Which basically means that it only loads the assemblies when they are actually needed.

The way i solved it was by using the more reliable GetReferencedAssemblies which loads all assemblies even if they are not being used.

```cs
var allAssemblies = new ReadOnlyCollection<Assembly>(
BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>().ToList());
```

Restarted tons of times and not one resolve crash :) Thanks everyone! For everyone looking for more information check out this SO answer: [Difference between AppDomain.GetAssemblies and BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477787/difference-between-appdomain-getassemblies-and-buildmanager-getreferencedassembli)