# Get all types from Solution who inherit specify class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I want to get all Types from Solution who inherit specify class. My Solution structure looks like:

```
 AssemblyTest (Solution)
|
 - ProjectOne (Class Library)
 - - BaseClass.cs (Class)
|
 - ProjectTwo (Class Library)
 - - FirstExampleClass.cs (Class inherit from BaseClass )
|
 - ConsoleApp (Console Application)
 - - SecondExampleClass.cs (Class inherit from BaseClass )
 - - Program.cs (Class inherit from BaseClass )
```

In `Program.cs` I want to get all Types who inherit `BaseClass`. For this, i use code:

```cs
var typesList = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                         .SelectMany(p => p.GetTypes()
                         .Where(t => typeof(BaseClass)
                         .IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsAbstract && t.IsPublic && t != typeof(BaseClass)));
```

But in `typesList` i get only one element -> `SecondExampleClass` from this same Project where exist `Program.cs`.

**BaseClass.cs**

```
public class BaseClass{}
```

**FirstExampleClass.cs**

```
public class FirstExampleClass : BaseClass{}
```

**SecondExampleClass.cs**

```
public class SecondExampleClass: BaseClass{}
```

P.S. `ConsoleApp` project has reference to `ProjectTwo` reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the assemblies probably aren't loaded into the current AppDomain yet.

> `AppDomain.GetAssemblies()` gives you all assemblies which have already been loaded into the current AppDomain. `BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()` (This method is only available in the .Net Framework System.Web.dll) returns a list of all assemblies referenced from Web.config and elsewhere, and it loads those assemblies into the current AppDomain.

See [Difference between AppDomain.GetAssemblies and BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477787/difference-between-appdomain-getassemblies-and-buildmanager-getreferencedassembl)