# Implicit type comparison with explicit type - C#

Tags: c#, type-conversion, implicit-typing

I've got an interesting issue with type comparison. I'm attempting to compare an implied type with an explicit type, to test if something is any sort of collection

```
var obField = value.GetType().InvokeMember(_stCollectionField, 
                              System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, 
                              null, value, null);

if (obField.GetType() != typeof(IEnumerable<object>))
{
    return true;
}
```

During my testing, I can ensure that `obField` will turn out to be a collection of objects. However, I'm finding that it will always run inside the check and `return true`, where instead I wish it to skip past that (becasue the two types are equal.)

A little debugging gives me the type of `obField` as `object {System.Collections.Generic.List<System.DateTime>}`.

**How can I go about matching that type?**

Thanks

Comment: If `obField` is of type `List<DateTime>` it clearly is not of type `IEnumerable<object>`... What was your question again?

Comment: List<T> extends IEnumerable<T>, no?

Comment: @Andy: True, but "==" does not mean "is extendable from", it means "is *equal* to" (and the same holds for "!="). Since `List<DateTime>` and `IEnumerable<object>` are not *equal*, "!=" evaluates to true.

Comment: can you compare the type names?

Comment: Good point, Heinzi, I hadn't thought of that, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx), as used here: [Getting all types that implement an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface-with-c-3-5)

For example:

```
if (typeof(IEnumerable<object>).IsAssignableFrom(obField.GetType())) { ... }
```

Comment: Addition: This will only work in .NET 4, because covariance for interfaces wasn't available earlier.

Comment: @Andy: If you want to test for any sort of collection then you'd probably be better off comparing against the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface.