# Dynamically load a class without specifying the assembly

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting all types that implement an interface with C# 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface-with-c-3-5)

I have an application with a number of DLL's referenced.  In those DLL's are many classes implementing `IStuff`.

How do I scan all the assemblies loaded at runtime and pull out a list of all classes implementing `IStuff`

Comment: Although the answers in that duplicate are a bit Linq-heavy there are also correct non-Linq answers tucked away in that question.