# Prevent Assembly.GetTypes() from loading dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have assembly A referencing assembly B. They are located in the same directory.

```
Type[] types = null;
try
{
  Assembly a = Assembly.Load("A.dll");
  types = a.GetTypes(); // loads B implicitly.
}
catch(ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
{
  types = ex.Types.Where(x=>x!=null);
}
```

How do I prevent B from being loaded? I want GetTypes() to run as if B wasn't available and to return only available types and null's for not available so I could execute 
`ex.Types.where(x=>x!=null);`

I want to use the trick from [How to prevent ReflectionTypeLoadException when calling Assembly.GetTypes()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889228/how-to-prevent-reflectiontypeloadexception-when-calling-assembly-gettypes)

This way I can get only types that don't depend on B and work with them.

**Update:**

I loaded A in the reflection as well as in the normal context. I used the reflection context A for calling GetTypes(). After getting types from the reflection context assembly, I had another problem. When I called Type.GetCustomAttributes(), I received the following exception

> It is illegal to reflect on the custom attributes of a Type loaded via
>   ReflectionOnlyGetType (see Assembly.ReflectionOnly) -- use
>   CustomAttributeData instead.

I solved it by getting the same type from the normal context assembly.

```
//... code omited for brevity
Type reflectionType = reflectionAssembly.GetTypes()[0];
//... code omited for brevity
Type goodType = normalAssembly.GetType(reflectionType.FullName);
```

This way I prevented loading of B and used types from A independent from B.

Comment: Erm, don't inherit from any types in B?  Which makes preventing loading B rather pointless.

Comment: The reason why I want to prevent B from loading is because I don't want the file to be locked so it can be compiled without restarting the application. It is used in some scenarios where it needs to be loaded.

Comment: So you want to change the base class of a derived class defined in A?  There are languages that support this.  They are in the dynamic language category, javascript, python, ruby.  Runtime errors instead of compile-time errors.

Comment: Assembly A is not used at this point. It is loaded as a part of initialisation. The list of types is needed for convention resolution in IOC. When types in A are used, B will be needed. I understand that.

Comment: Clearly that's not the way it works.  Reflecting a type is very much *using* the type, even if you don't yet generate code for it.  Code is meaningless to Reflection.

Comment: I updated the question. By using that trick (see the link) you can reflect types partially. ReflectionTypeLoadException will only return types that don't derive from types in B. My bad. I didn't mention it at the beginning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

look at using `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad()` which looks to not load dependencies.  not sure if it will return types that reference that dependency or not as i've not tried to do it before.

Comment: Yes, it worked. It doesn't return the referencing types but you can get independent types, which is what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's 2022, and .NET 6 is here, so the solution mentioned above is officially obsolete.

Here is a new solution:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/master/docs/specs/typeloader.md

Apparently, this is an archived experimental repository, so you have to embed the [code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/archive/src/System.Reflection.TypeLoader) into your project manually. Take note of the license.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).