# Getting a list of types in an assembly that inherit from a specific interface

Tags: c#, reflection, gettype

**Please read before marking as duplicate, already answered, on hold, or off topic.**

First of all, I know there are SIMILAR question here, with very good answers. Unfortunately they do not answer my question.

My goal: to create a list of all of the types within an assembly that inherit from a specific interface. This assembly may be located at a local path or a UNC path.

My problem: First, I know how to load an assembly, both from a UNC and a local path, and I know how to use GetTypes(). Many of you may know that GetTypes() has it's own issue. Specifically, it will raise an exception if any of the Types inherit from another type that cannot be loaded. [How to prevent ReflectionTypeLoadException when calling Assembly.GetTypes()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889228/how-to-prevent-reflectiontypeloadexception-when-calling-assembly-gettypes) for instance. The problem is, I don't need to load any of the dependencies. I only need to see if a type declared in the assembly inherits from an other specific type.

some code as an example. This is just the first step, to retrieve the types in the assembly:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(assemblyPath));

Type[] myTypes = GetLoadableTypes(asm);

public static Type[] GetLoadableTypes(Assembly assembly)
{
    // TODO: Argument validation
    try
    {
        return assembly.GetTypes();
    }
    catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
    {
        return e.Types.Where(t => t != null);
    }
}
```

If any of the Types inside of the assembly inherit from a type that cannot be loaded, a ReflectionTypeLoadException exception will be thrown and they will show up as null inside of e.Types, so there is still no information on them. So I guess I can't use GetTypes still.

For completeness, here is a reference to my original question.
[How to get Type information when ReflectionTypeLoadException is thrown from Assembly.GetType()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251600/how-to-get-type-information-when-reflectiontypeloadexception-is-thrown-from-asse)

Comment: To me, that looks like an exact duplicate of the question you linked. It also looks like exactly the question you previously posted that was put on-hold. How is this question different?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Type information when ReflectionTypeLoadException is thrown from Assembly.GetType()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251600/how-to-get-type-information-when-reflectiontypeloadexception-is-thrown-from-asse)

Comment: While I agree that it is very close in both cases, there was a VERY specific point that this question differs on: you still cannot get any information on a type if its dependencies cannot be loaded as well. I'm really not sure how to make that any clearer or where the question I linked deals with that aspect. If I missed something there, please point it out. As far as my question on hold, I thought I had to ask the question in a different way and give more information so I created this one. Then I realized I could have just edited the previous question.

Answer (score 0):

OK, made some headway with this and, unless I want to write my own metadata parser, it looks like this is what I am stuck with so I thought I'd share. I'll try to give the pros and cons.

This answer all revolves around using an event handler for the
`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve` 
event. It should be pointed out that this event is only raised when an assembly's dependencies are being resolved. I didn't understand that at first but what it simply means is that the event is not fired for the assembly you are trying to load, but any dependencies in that assembly, which makes sense. Why raise that event when you have to have a starting point in the first place. For my solution, this event will be raised when I call .GetTypes().

Before I post the code let me explain the idea and what's good and bad about it. The idea is that, if I have a dependency, the event will be raised. In the event, I will first check a dictionary, created before hand, of all of the assemblies found in the same folder (including subfolders) as the original assembly. If the args.Name is found in that dictionary, then I read in that assembly and return it from the event. If it's not in the list, I attempt to load the assembly by name only, meaning the dependency assembly must either be part of the project or installed in the local GAC.

I already hinted at some of the cons here, so let's start with those.
Since I'm not just looking at metadata to tell me what dependencies are in the main assembly (in other words those dependencies must be loaded), if a dependency's assembly cannot be found with the original assembly (in the same folder or subfolders), and the dependency is not installed in the local GAC, or referenced in the project, GetTypes() will still throw a ReflectionTypeLoadException exception. It may seem like a rare case to run in to a situation where an dependency assembly is not located with the original assembly or installed in the GAC but I would give PRISM as an example of a situation where that may happen. PRISMs assemblies do not necessarily get installed into the GAC and are not always going to be copied local.

So what's good about this method? Well mainly that it gives you at least some way to handle 99% of the situations where you don't have a dependency's assembly in hand.

One or two final thoughts (actually gotchas) before the code. I use AssemblyName to create a dictionary bases on the assembly's full name without actually loading (either straight out or by ReflectionOnlyLoad) an assembly. There are two ways you can create an instance of AssemblyName, either by the constructor where you pass in the path to the assembly, or with a static method, GetAssemblyName(path). The constructor seems to only handle local paths where GetAssemblyName() can handle a UNC path. Those are the gotchas: don't load the assembly just to get the name and make sure you don't limit yourself to local paths.

Finally, some code:

```
public class TestClass
{
    //This dictionary will hold a list of the full path for an assembly, indexed by the assembly's full name
    private Dictionary<string, string> _allAsms = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to list all of the Types inside an assembly and any interfaces those types inherit from.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pathName">The path of the original assembly, without the assembly file</param>
    /// <param name="fileName">The name of the assembly file as it is found on disk.</param>
    public void Search(string pathName, string fileName)
    {

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve);

        //Getting a list of all possible assembly files that exist in the same location as the original assembly
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(pathName, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        Assembly asm;
        AssemblyName name;

        if (!pathName.EndsWith("\\"))
            pathName += "\\";

        foreach (string path in filePaths)
        {
            name = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(path);

            if (!_allAsms.ContainsKey(name.FullName))
                _allAsms.Add(name.FullName, path);
        }

        //This is where we are loading the originaly assembly
        asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(File.ReadAllBytes(pathName + fileName));

        Console.WriteLine("Opened assembly:{0}", fileName);

        //And this is where the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve will start to be raised
        foreach (Type t in asm.GetTypes())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  " + t.FullName);
            //Get the interfaces for the type;
            foreach (Type dep in t.GetInterfaces())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("    " + dep.FullName);
            }
        }
    }

    private Assembly CurrentDomain_ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        if (_allAsms.ContainsKey(args.Name))
            return Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(File.ReadAllBytes(_allAsms[args.Name]));
        else
            return System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(args.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To check if a type implements a specific interface you can use this:

```
typeof(yourInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type)
```

However, if the type could not be loaded there is no information available on it, and you have no chance to figure out whether it implements a specific interface or not.

Comment: Since the OP explicitly states their problem is that the types in question can't be loaded, I'm not sure what value your answer has.

Comment: This may help to avoid adding another instance where ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve needs to be raised, but that's about it.