# Cannot retrieve TypeInfo(s) from assembly due to ReflectionTypeLoadException

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

I am trying to retrieve all defined types into a .NET assembly by using `System.Reflection` in C#. First I load the assembly:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\...\myassembly.dll");
```

Then I try to get all the `TypeInfo` for the types in the assembly:

```
try {
    var types = assembly.DefinedTypes;
}
catch(ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
{
    var errorMessage = new StringBuilder();
    errorMessage.AppendLine($"Error loading defined types in assembly {this.assembly.FullName}. Found {ex.LoaderExceptions.Length} errors:");

    foreach (var innerException in ex.LoaderExceptions)
    {
        errorMessage.AppendLine($"{innerException.GetType().Name} - {innerException.HResult}: {innerException.Message}");
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException(errorMessage.ToString(), ex);
}
```

#### Fail

The failure I have is `ReflectionTypeLoadException` and I get in `ex.LoaderExceptions` a lot of exceptions like:

> -2146233054: Could not load type 'MyType' from assembly 'myassembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because the method '.ctor' has no implementation (no RVA)

#### Regarding the reflection context

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889228/how-to-prevent-reflectiontypeloadexception-when-calling-assembly-gettypes) which deals about this same problem, one of the suggestions was to use:

```
var assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom("C:\...\myassembly.dll");
```

Which seemed pretty logic. However it did not work.

#### My question

My question is simple: how can I get all the `TypeInfo` from the available types by ignoring errors on types that are not fully defined in the assembly or that lack implementation?

I know that `ex.Types` will give me a list of types I can use from the exception, but that would give me a `System.Type` not a `System.Reflection.TypeInfo`. I want the latter as it has more information about the types which I need. The question I linked does not deal with this problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `TypeInfo` from the `Type` object by calling the `IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo` extension method. So it should be as simple as this:

```
var typeInfo = ex.Types.Select(IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo).ToArray();
```

Comment: Ok, let me try this!

Comment: I have some failures but I think that is because we need to first filter out from `ex.Types` the `null` ones and on the others we should apply the `Select` clause! I will try that...

Comment: Very cool, it works like this: `ex.Types.Where(t => t != null).Select(IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo)`