# Iterating through list of extended classes and dynamically creating objects

Tags: c#, class, derived-class

I would like to iterate through a list of classes that extend class "A" and create objects of the extended classes' type.

Is there a way to replace the className in "new className();" with a variable or do I have to use a switch statement to create objects of different types?

```
List <A> listOfSubClasses; //A list of classes that all extend "A"
List <A> objects; //List to hold created objects
int[] variable; 
foreach (A subClass in listOfSubClasses){
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){ //Let's say I want to create 3 objects of every class
        objects.Add (new subClass()); //This is the line my question refers to
        objects[objects.Count - 1].someParameter = variable[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: `List <A> listOfSubClasses;` and `List <A> objects;` are both lists of **objects**

Comment: You might need something like `List<Type>`

Comment: Additionally to using `List<Type>` for keeping the (sub-classed) types you want to create instances from, look into leveraging `Activator.CreateInstance(Type)` for your needs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `List<Type>` to store the types you want to instanciate, and then, use [System.Activator.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.8) to create the instances from the type

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class A
{
    public int someParameter;
}
public class B : A {}
public class C : A {}
public class D : A {}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List <Type> listOfSubClasses = new List<Type>
        {
            typeof(B),
            typeof(C),
            typeof(D)
        };
        List <A> objects = new List<A>();

        int[] variable = { 1, 2, 3 }; 
        foreach (var subClass in listOfSubClasses) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                objects.Add((A)Activator.CreateInstance(subClass));
                objects[objects.Count - 1].someParameter = variable[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will freely admit that i am an insufferable nitpicker (sometimes), but _someProperty_ here is actually a field, not a property. I just found that funny... okay, okay, i'll take my coat and leave... ;-)

Comment: @elgonzo I noticed that few minutes ago, but I was too lazy to modify that. Feel free to edit :)

Comment: I happily oblige and vandalized your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection for that. (I haven't checked this solution on my machine, so there may be minor differences.)

```
using System;

// ...

List<Type> listOfSubClasses =
    from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    from type in assembly.GetTypes()
    where type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(A))
    select type;

List<A> objects;
int[] variable; 
foreach (Type subClass in listOfSubClasses) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        objects.Add((A)Activator.CreateInstance(subClass));
        objects[objects.Count - 1].someParameter = variable[i];
    }
}
```

`Activator.CreateInstance` uses the default constructor to create an object, but there are other overloads if you need something else.

The solution for providing all subclasses of a class is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928464/for-an-object-can-i-get-all-its-subclasses-using-reflection-or-other-ways).