# Iterate Nested Classes to Get Field Info

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How do you iterate through nested classes to get the property field of each nested class?

Nested Classes:

```
public static class Permissions
{
    public static class Aircraft
    {
        public const string View = "Permissions.Aircraft.View";
        public const string Create = "Permissions.Aircraft.Create";
        public const string Edit = "Permissions.Aircraft.Edit";
        public const string Delete = "Permissions.Aircraft.Delete";
    }

    public static class TripRecord
    {
        public const string View = "Permissions.TripRecord.View";
        public const string Create = "Permissions.TripRecord.Create";
        public const string Edit = "Permissions.TripRecord.Edit";
        public const string Delete = "Permissions.TripRecord.Delete";
    }
}
```

This is what I have:

```
        var PermissionType = typeof(Permissions);
        var members = PermissionType.GetMembers();

        foreach (MemberInfo property in members)
        {

            FieldInfo[] fields = property.GetType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
            foreach (FieldInfo fi in fields)
            {
                var s = fi.GetValue(null).ToString();
            }
        }
```

This fails because the fields are blank.

Desired output:

```
Permissions.Aircraft.View   
Permissions.Aircraft.Create 
Permissions.Aircraft.Edit
Permissions.Aircraft.Delete 
Permissions.TripRecord.View 
Permissions.TripRecord.Create
Permissions.TripRecord.Edit 
Permissions.TripRecord.Delete
```

Comment: Why not just use a `[Flags]` bitfield enum?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For an object, can I get all its subclasses using reflection or other ways?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928464/for-an-object-can-i-get-all-its-subclasses-using-reflection-or-other-ways)

Comment: @TimRoberts that proposed duplicate is a different problem. That question is about subclasses (ie. inheritance) and this question is about nested types/classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`property` is already the type object, you just need to cast it to `Type`

```
foreach (MemberInfo property in members)
{
    if(property is Type propertyType)
    {
        var fields = propertyType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (var fi in fields)
        {
            var s = fi.GetValue(null).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `GetFields` method you should use the [Type.GetNestedTypes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getnestedtypes?view=net-7.0) method.

```cs
Type permissionType = typeof(Permissions);
Type[] nestedTypes = permissionType.GetNestedTypes();

// iterate thru the nested classes (in our code they are all the nested types are classes)
foreach (Type nestedType in nestedTypes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Nested type is {0}.", nestedType.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this only lists the class names, Aircraft & Trip Record.  The desired output is all of the const strings, apologies for not being clearer.