# How to: Retrieve a Plugin from a PluginAssembly

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to get a plugin from a pluginassembly object using early bindings.

```
List<PluginAssembly> pluginList;
pluginList = xrmContext.PluginAssemblySet
    .Where(Plugin => Plugin.SolutionId == solution.Id).ToList();
foreach (PluginAssembly tempPlugin in pluginList)
{...}
```

Now I want to retrieve the Plugins in the assembly but I can't seem to find a class named `Plugin` or a clear defined collection in the `PluginAssembly` object.

How do I retrieve the Plugin object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to retrieve pluginTypes objects.

It just wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Plugins have to implement IPlugin.  I'm not sure what information PluginAssembly gives you, but I'm guessing you should be able to use reflection to get the classes in the assembly, and then determine if they implement IPlugin or not.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface-with-c-sharp-3-5) for help with that.