# Autofac provide componentregister to class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, autofac, multi-tenant

I need to access the autofac component register to find out which types have been registered that match a certain interface and name.

I found the way to do this in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061472/get-all-registered-implementations-of-an-interface-in-autofac)

```
var types = scope.ComponentRegistry.Registrations
    .SelectMany(r => r.Services.OfType<IServiceWithType>(), (r, s) => new { r, s })
    .Where(rs => rs.s.ServiceType.Implements<T>())
    .Select(rs => rs.r.Activator.LimitType);
```

How can I pass in the scope, component registry and registrations to my class so it can perform this internally.

The reason for doing it this way is that I'm trying to resolve a asp.net mvc controller for which I only have a name of (no namespace or concrete type) and it can be overridden using autofacs multitenancy support.

So I need to resolve a string like  "HomeController" to an actual HomeController type depending on what has been registered in Autofac.

All of this would be done in a controllerfactory.

Comment: I'm quite sure that there is more elegant solution than messing with the `ComponentRegistry`... Autofac automatically registers the `ILifetimeScope` in the container.  So in your class's constructor you can depend on the `ILifetimeScope` and from that you can get the `ComponentRegistry`.

Comment: I'd like to believe there is a better way but I really cant think of any way to map a string name to an actual type

Comment: Any ideas on where to start looking?

Comment: I'm following a similar approach as described by Zack Owens here http://weblogs.asp.net/zowens/archive/2010/06/07/mulit-tenant-asp-net-mvc-controllers.aspx

Comment: It sounds like you want to use [Named Services](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/TypedNamedAndKeyedServices)