# Autofac - get all instances of classes whose interface implements specific interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac

Let's say I have an interface called `IBaseInterface`.
Then there are two interfaces that inherit this interface:

```
IFirstConcreteInterface : IBaseInterface
```

and

```
ISecondConcreteInterface : IBaseInterface
```

Now I have two classes that implement the concrete interfaces:

```
FirstConcreteClass : IFirstConcreteInterface
```

and

```
SecondConcreteClass : ISecondConcreteInterface
```

The instances of these classes have been registered with autofac at `Startup.cs`.

Here's my question:

How can I get the instances of all classes whose interfaces inherit from `IBaseInterface` (instance of `FirstConcreteClass` and `SecondConcreteClass` in this example) by using autofac? I don't need them in the `Startup.cs` but in a different class.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Related: [Get a list of all registered objects implementing a certain interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369861/get-a-list-of-all-registered-objects-implementing-a-certain-interface) and [Get all registered implementations of an interface in Autofac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061472/get-all-registered-implementations-of-an-interface-in-autofac)

Comment: From a comment on the first linked question: "Autofac doesn't really support doing what you're asking" but there are valid answers

Comment: Yes, the following answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24389668/9888512