# Get all c# Types that implements an interface first but no derived classes

Tags: c#, reflection

related to [Getting all types that implement an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733) we can easily get all Types in the Assembly that implements a specific interface.

Example:

```
interface IFace
{
}

class Face : IFace
{
}

class TwoFace : Face
{
}
```

For this structure, we will find *both* classes via reflection, i.e. all classes that are derived from the first implementation too, using

```
GetTypes().Where(
  type => type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IFace))
)
```

So the **question** is: *how can I restrict the result to the base class that initially implements the interface?!*
In this example: only class type *Face* is relevant.

Comment: Note: iterating all found classes/types, checking for if one is derived from another not seems practical, neither performant to me

Comment: That's a limitation of using reflection. An interface doesn't know which classes implement it so you can't get at them without iterating over everything. If you want better performance, you probably need Roslyn.

Comment: @childno.de once you are already iterating all types in the assembly, it isn't going to have any additional performance impact to simply check the inheritance of thm

Comment: You could trick it by having unwanted classes to implement some `IFaceFake` interface in addition.

Comment: @childno.de: Do you have *evidence* for thinking it's impractical? It's almost never a good idea to guess about performance.

Comment: @MarcGravell / JonSkeet ok, I have to test if it really matters, but it's code that runs in realtime application context, so yes, for me performance matters. (nevertheless, reflecting is a really bad idea here under this circumstances ;D but I can't avoid it when loading assemblies by runtime. So I intend to avoid any useless actions / iterations where possible)

Comment: @childno.de you misunderstand me; you are *already* using reflection here - it is simply the "check for subtypes" that isn't going to matter. If you don't want to use reflection, then either hard-code the list, or put the list into a configuration file somewhere (still *some* reflection to load by name, but much much less).

Comment: @MarcGravell no, didn't misunderstood you ;) I just wanted to point out that it is clear to me using reflection has more impact to performance than an additional iterator (I can't meter yet).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Firstly, I'd use `Type.IsAssignableFrom` rather than `GetInterfaces`, but then all you need to do is exclude types whose parent type is already in the set:

```
var allClasses = types.Where(type => typeof(IFace).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                      .ToList(); // Or use a HashSet, for better Contains perf.
var firstImplementations = allClasses
      .Except(allClasses.Where(t => allClasses.Contains(t.BaseType)));
```

Or as noted in comments, equivalently:

```
var firstImplementations = allClasses.Where(t => !allClasses.Contains(t.BaseType));
```

Note that this will *not* return a class which derives from a class which implements an interface, but *reimplements* it.

Comment: Why not just `allClasses.Where(t => !allClasses.Contains(t.BaseType))`?

Comment: @BenAaronson: `Except` is generally more efficient, that's all. But yes, they're basically equivalent.

Comment: It is? That feels like it wants a question of its own!

Comment: @BenAaronson: Not really - just read https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-17-except.aspx (In this case, it may not be more efficient, in fact. I think I haven't had enough coffee.)

Comment: ok, thank you so far. seems to that it rans into an StackOverflow for me when using restricted `allClasses` again in the inner linq expression.. using outer `types` for `Contains(baseType)` check works fine, even it iterates the whole assembly type list again ;(

Comment: @childno.de: What do you mean by "restricted"? And when you say "seems to that it rans into an StackOverflow" do you mean you'd expect it to, or that it actually does? I can't see why there's be a stack overflow problem at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet with "restricted" I meant the already filtered list from the first Where. I actually ran into one `System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateWhereIterator>c__Iterator1D`1[System.Type].MoveNext ()`. But it's not plain .net stack but a derived Mono .. so perhaps there is a bug in that implementation.

Comment: @childno.de: It's hard to understand exactly what you mean without some test code. With the exact code I've given, there should be no problem. If you could provide a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem, I should be able to help more.

Comment: I found the missing paren, here it is: )