# Get an instance for each class that implements an Interface

Tags: c#, inherited

In order to solve a problem that I have in my solution using reflection, I need to specify the following code to show the user a CheckedListBox which exposes a list of conditions that they have to choose, and according with their choose  it modifies a certain behavior in the application. 
At this time, I don't have problem to get the string name of the inherited classes thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface) post, but I couldn't figure out how to get an instance of each one.

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Intance", typeof(IConditions)); //INSTANCE of the inherited class
        table.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string)); //name of the inherited class

        //list of all types that implement IConditions interface
        var interfaceName = typeof(IConditions);
        List<Type> inheritedTypes = (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
            .Where(p => interfaceName.IsAssignableFrom(p) && p != interfaceName)).ToList();

        foreach (Type type in inheritedTypes)
        {
            IConditions i; //here is where I don't know how to get the instance of the Type indicated by 'type' variable

            //I.E: IConditions I = new ConditionOlderThan20(); where 'ConditionOlderThan20' is a class which implements IConditions interface

            table.Rows.Add(i, type.Name);
        }
```

Is possible to get an object? What is the better approach to deal with problems like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
IConditions i = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IConditions;
```

*Note:* This will fail if `type` does not have parameterless constructor. You can use then version with parameters:

```
public static Object CreateInstance(Type type, params Object[] args)
```

Comment: Excellent Konrad!! This is what I need! I my case the constructor is not a problem, but is a valid aclaration.