# Reflection Reading DLL and adding that to a list of type Interface

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have a List of type ITemp. ITemp is a interface.

```
List<ITemp> temp = new List<ITemp>();
```

Now what I have to do is to read all the dlls from Specific file Location and add that into this temp list
so what I am doing is this :

```
 List<Assembly> allAssemblies = new List<Assembly>();
 string path = Path.GetDirectoryName("C:\\TemplatesDLL\\");

 foreach (string dll in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll"))
 {
     allAssemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFile(dll));
 }

  foreach (Assembly assembly in allAssemblies)
{
   var DLL = Assembly.LoadFile(assembly.Location.ToString());
    foreach (var t in DLL.GetTypes())
    {
         Activator.CreateInstance(t);
          var constructors = t.GetConstructors();
          temp.Add(t.GetConstructors()); // here I have to add all the dll that implements ITemp interfaces
      }
 }
```

adding the interface something like this if its in the same project

```
temp.Add(new TestTemp());
```

here TestTemp is a C# file in the same project. Now I move this TestTemp in to a DLL file. And Read it from the same application and add into the list.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sounds like a job for MEF... That said, what's the problem you are having?

Comment: How to add like the way I have added in temp.add(new TestTemp()); after loading all the DLLs

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

```
    List<Assembly> allAssemblies = new List<Assembly>();
    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName("C:\\TemplatesDLL\\");

    List<ITemp> temp = new List<ITemp>();
    foreach (string dll in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll"))
    {
          allAssemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFile(dll));
    }
    foreach (Assembly assembly in allAssemblies)
    {
         var DLL = Assembly.LoadFile(assembly.Location.ToString());
         Type[] types = DLL.GetTypes();
         if (typeof(ITemp).IsAssignableFrom(types[0]))
         {
              temp.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(types[0]) as ITemp); //adding all the instance into the list that is what I was looking for.
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually needed to do this recently.  This example only gets the first type, but you could easily modify it to return a list and iterate the list.

```
var dll = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\SimplePlugin.dll");
Type pluginType = dll.GetExportedTypes()
    .Where(t => typeof(SimplePluginContracts.ISomePlugin).IsAssignableFrom(t) 
         && !t.IsInterface).First();

SimplePluginContracts.ISomePlugin plugin = 
    (SimplePluginContracts.ISomePlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(pluginType);
```

This question covers variations on this, and the top answer has a good discussion of nuances of this technique that my simple example doesn't handle:

[Getting all types that implement an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface)

You might consider also filtering out non-public classes, in case your DLL has some classes not intended to be loaded which also implement the interface.