# Get all class types that implement a specific interface using VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, reflection, interface

I want to load all Forms that implement the interface `IFormLoadSubscriber`.

**Interface**

```
Namespace Interfaces
    Public Interface IFormLoadSubscriber

    End Interface
End Namespace
```

At this time it doesn't add anything, subscribing to it is enough.

**Form**

```
Namespace Forms
    Public Class MainForm
        Inherits Base.Base
        Implements IFormLoadSubscriber

    End Class
End Namespace
```

That Base.Base is a form that enforces base behavior.

**What I have**

```
Private Shared Function GetSubscribers() As List(Of Type)
    Dim type = GetType(IFormLoadSubscriber)
    Dim subscribers = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() _
                      .Where(Function(x) type.IsAssignableFrom(type)) _
                      .Select(Function(x) x.GetTypes())

    Return subscribers
End Function
```

**The problem**

The above code does not work as expected, because it returns a large list of lists, containing all sorts of types. If mine is included, it's impossible to find manually. At any rate, this is not what I need.

**The question**

How do I change the above code so that it returns only one class (as only one class implements `IFormLoadSubscriber`), in this case my MainForm?

Comment: Look at this part: `type.IsAssignableFrom(type)`

Comment: Well spotted, that doesn't seem right ... how would I fix that? I suppose I would need something like `.Where(Function(x) x.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(type))` but that doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing it to

```
Private Shared Function GetSubscribers() As List(Of Type)
    Dim type = GetType(IFormLoadSubscriber)
    Dim subscribers = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() _
                      .SelectMany(Function(x) x.GetTypes()) _
                      .Where(Function(x) type.IsAssignableFrom(x))

    Return subscribers
End Function
```

[Getting all types that implement an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface)

Comment: That works! But, a minor note, if I don't add `.Where(Function(x) x IsNot type)` it also returns `IFormLoadSubscriber`, which is not what I want (that would cause errors) and it's quite unexpected, as `IFormLoadSubscriber` does not implement itself obviously...

Answer (score 2):

`SelectMany` will flatten than list of lists.

```
Dim subscribers = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() _
                      .SelectMany(Function(x) x.GetTypes() _
                                  .Where(Function(y) type.IsAssignableFrom(y)))
```

I have also moved the `Where` clause inside the SelectMany.

Your where clause is also incorrect, `type.IsAssignableFrom(type)` is always going to be true.