# Get a class method that implements an interface defined in a different DLL

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

My case is a little complicated, so I am explaining it with an example.

Here is my case:

`fileA.cs`:

```
namespace companyA.testA
{
    public interface ITest
    {
        int Add(int a, int b);
    }
}
```

**Note**: `fileA.cs` will be compiled to `fileA.dll`

`fileB.cs`:

```
namespace companyA.testB  ////note here a different namespace 
{
    public class ITestImplementation: ITest
    {
        public int Add(int a,int b)
        {
            return a+b;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: `fileB.cs` will be compiled to `fileB.dll`.

Now I have `run.cs`:

```
using System.Reflection;

public class RunDLL
{
    static void Main(string [] args)
    {
        Assembly asm;
        asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("fileB.dll");

        //Suppose "fileB.dll" is not created by me. Instead, it is from outside.
        //So I do not know the namespace and class name in "fileB.cs".
        //Then I want to get the method "Add" defined in "fileB.cs"
        //Is this possible to do?
    }
}
```

There is an answer here ([Getting all types that implement an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface)):

```
//answer from other thread, NOT mine:
var type = typeof(IMyInterface);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p));
```

But it seems not be able to work in my case.

Comment: Your last code example is using IMyInterface, but this doesn't correlate with anything in the previous examples.

Comment: @JonathonChase The last code is not mine. Added a comment in case of confusion. THanks.

Comment: @derek so instead of IMyInterface it would be var type = typeof(ITest); ?

Comment: @TlonXP The issue is not knowing the interface, just the method name and assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seeing as you already have the assembly available right there as `asm`:

```
   var typesWithAddMethod = 
       from type in asm.GetTypes()
       from method in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
       where method.Name == "Add"
       select type;
```