# Instantiate large number of classes

Tags: c#, .net-core

At the moment I have a list of classes like this:

```
public List<Algo> AlgoList = new List<Algo>
{
    new BastionAlgo(),
    new BitcoreAlgo(),
    new Blake2SAlgo(),
    new BlakeAlgo(),
    new BlakeCoinAlgo(),
    new BmwAlgo(),
    new C11FlaxAlgo(),
    new CryptolightAlgo(),
    new CryptonightAlgo(),
    ...
};
```

As I add and remove classes I would prefer not to have to maintain a long list.
Is there a way to find and instantiate all the classes that extend another in .net core 2?

Thank you in advance for you assistance.

Comment: This question, as asked, is a poor fit for SO.  But the term you are looking for is Reflection.  A little Google-Fu should net you quite a few results.

Comment: I should have include the research I had done. How would you recommend improving the "fit"?

Comment: I think I didn't give your question much thought before commenting.  I apologize.  The first glance looked like you were asking for a tutorial to me.  But on further review I see my mistake.  Please ignore my previous comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is, see [Getting all types that implement an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface)

```
var type = typeof(Algo);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p));
```

If they all have parameterless constructors you can use [Activator.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx) to create instances

```
AlgoList = types.Select(t => Activator.CreateInstance(t)).ToList();
```