# How to register DI services for specific Interface type?

Tags: c#, reflection, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have `interface IServiceHandlerAsync<T>` and I have following service registrations

```
services.AddScoped<SoftwareTestService>();
services.AddScoped<SoftwareTestCaseService>();
services.AddScoped<SoftwareTestCaseStepService>();
services.AddScoped<SoftwareTestCaseStepResultService>();
```

where each of these services are inherited from `interface IServiceHandlerAsync<T>`

is it possible to resolve and register aforamentioned services without specifying every service explicitely by using interface (I am thinking that reflection may do the work) ?

Algorithmic example would be

```
foreach (var service in .getResolvedServices<IServiceHandlerAsync>)
{
    services.AddScoped(service);
}
```

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with the following solution.

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(mytype => mytype.GetInterface(typeof(IServiceHandlerAsync<>).Name) != null)
            .ForEach(appCoreService => services.AddScoped(appCoreService));
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: No

Long answer: No - not using functionality provided out of the box by `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions`. These packages provide very basic functionality and were originally built to make use of the early version of the dotnet standard (like 1.1 - ~1.5) which contained hardly any reflection functionalities. Thus they force you do declare your dependencies in an explicit way:

```cs
   services.AddScoped<SoftwareTestService>();
   services.AddScoped<SoftwareTestCaseService>();
   services.AddScoped<SoftwareTestCaseStepService>();
   services.AddScoped<SoftwareTestCaseStepResultService>();
```

A more important question for me is - If you register multiple implementations of your `IServiceHandlerAsync` interface, how do you decide which one you are going to get/need?

You see `IServiceprovider.GetService<IServiceHandlerAsync>` will only return one of them (and there is no specification as to which one of the 4 you registered you're going to get) while `IServiceprovider.GetServices<IServiceHandlerAsync>` will return all of them, leaving you with the task of sorting out which one you´ll be needing - which is exactly something that dependency injection is supposed to take off your shoulders.

Comment: I am using generic Interface for crud operations, and I know that all inherited members of `IServiceHandlerAsync<T>` needed to be registered as service. I ended up with solution which can be seen below.