# C# get unreferenced assemblies

Tags: c#, reflection

## The problem

I'm working on a project with a plugin like system. The project structure is defined as follows:

```
- Solution
    - Project A (Cli)
    - Project B (Core logic)
    - Project C (Plugin)
```

`Project A` is the startup project, `Project B` contains the core logic and `Project C` is a plugin, which implements an interface in `project B`. `Project A` only has a reference to `Project B` and `Project C` only has a reference to `Project B`.

To visualize:
[image: visualization]

Since I do not reference `Project C` from `Project B` (and do not instantiate the class directly), code like `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` (inside `Project B`) does **not** return `Project C`.

However, once I do (from `Project B`): `var MyImplementation = new MyImplementation()`, `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` **does** return the assembly, since it's known and loaded at runtime as I instantiated the class `MyImplementation` explicitly from code.

## The question

From `Project B`, I want to get all assemblies which implement a specific interface from `Project B` and instantiate them.

So, how do I get these (seemingly) unknown assemblies to get loaded at runtime?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface is this helping?

Comment: @LouisGo unfortunately, `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` does not contain the assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to know if an assembly contains a class that implement your interface without loading it.

What you can do is provide a directory where you put all your plugins assemblies.

So you can load your plugins in your AppDomain like this :

```cs
public static Assembly[] MyPlugins { get; private set; }

public static void LoadAssemblies()
{
   MyPlugins = Directory.GetFiles(lookingDirectory, "*.dll")
                .Select(assemblyPath =>
                {
                    AssemblyName an = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(assemblyPath);
                    return Assembly.Load(an);
                })
                .ToArray();
}
```

And then you can find all types that implements your interface like this :

```cs
MyPlugins.SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
    .Where(type => typeof(IYourInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    .Select(type => (IYourInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(type))
```

And then you can iterate on each implementation of your interface to call a shared method for example.

Comment: Yes, I thought about having a `plugin` folder and putting DLL's into it. If that's the only way, then I might do that.

Comment: Yes you need a way to identify which assembly contains your plugins.

Comment: You could also name your plugins with a suffix or prefix and filter all dlls that are in your root folder and are named this way

Comment: Or you can also provide a command in your cli like `loadplugin "Path/ToMyPlugin"` and save this path in config file. In each loading of your program you can read your file and reload  all given assemblies