# ASP .Net Core get all classes that Implement interface and call their methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have an asp.net core 3.1 web application

I have an **Interface** which is implemented by 3 classes to configure database mapping. I want to call the method automatically during application configuration setup.

Following is my interface and their implementation.

```
public interface IMongoMapper
    {
        void Configure();
    }
 class TenantMap : IMongoMapper
{
    public void Configure()
    {
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Entities.Tenant>(cm =>
        {
            cm.AutoMap();
        });
    }
}
class CourseMap : IMongoMapper
    {
        public void Configure()
        {
            BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Course>(cm =>
            {
                cm.AutoMap();
            });
        }
    }
```

> How to get all the classes that implement interface and call Configure
>   method appropriately?

Comment: Show how you are getting instances of these classes in your application startup

Comment: I don't know the way except DI. Is it possible to call method via DI?

Comment: I think DI is only for injection. SO in application startup I am just injecting those

Comment: You can use Reflection to get all types implementing that interface, then use Activator.CreateInstance() and execute Configure method on created instances

Comment: These classes seem to contain (simple) configuration. Why do you need to register and resolve them through your DI container? I would expect those classes to be created and consumed at startup, at which point you typically don't have (nor need) a container).

Comment: OK I got your point. So will it be a good practice to use reflection in Startup.cs? @Steven

Comment: Can you elaborate why you need to use reflection at all at this point? Why can't you instantiate a list of `IMongoMapper` instances, loop over them, and call their `Configure` method?

Comment: this is what I am asking. The only method I know is by reflection. Can you tell me how to loop over IMongoMapper instances via example? and where should I call the configure method? Because mongo mapping will be called once when the application starts

Comment: If you have all of those in the same assembly you can `typeof(SomeTypeInThatAssembly).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(x=> x.Implements(typeof(IMongoMapper))).ForEach(x=> ((IMongoMapper) Activator.CreateInstance(x)).Configure())` if you break this ugly code into its individual parts you'll know what it's doing. One part there that is not native to .net is the extension method "Implements", you can implement this method elsewhere to use here

Comment: I'd share my ugly code for "implements", but it revolves around checking if `t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == interfaceType)` or if its base types recursively satisfy this condition. Obviously you might want to check if the class has any empty constructors first and other checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scope.ServiceProvider.GetServices<IMongoMapper>();` to get all classes that implement `IMongoMapper` interface.

You can use an extension method and call it in `Configure` method in `startup` class.

```cs
public static void IntializeMapping(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        var mappers = scope.ServiceProvider.GetServices<IMongoMapper>();
        foreach (var map in mappers)
        {
             map.Configure();
        }
    }
}
```

and use it in `startup` class

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.IntializeMapping();
}
```

**Update**

According to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1#initialize-db-with-test-data) better way is use this

```cs
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        try
        {
            var mappers = scope.ServiceProvider.GetServices<IMongoMapper>();
            foreach (var map in mappers)
            {
                 map.Configure();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             var logger = service.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
             logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred mapping");
        }
    }
    await host.RunAsync();
}
```

```cs
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

> Microsoft Documentation
>   In older tutorials, you may see similar code in the `Configure` method in `Startup.cs`. We recommend that you use the `Configure` method only to set up the request pipeline. Application startup code belongs in the Main method.
>
> Now the first time you run the application, the database will be created and seeded with test data. Whenever you change your data model, you can delete the database, update your seed method, and start afresh with a new database the same way. In later tutorials, you'll see how to modify the database when the data model changes, without deleting and re-creating it.

Comment: WHat if I make the extension via IServiceCollection and use in Configure Service method. What difference does it make to use in Configure method vs ConfigurationService method

Comment: aspcore configure vs configure service

Comment: @HaseebKhan i updated my answer and hope to help you :)

Comment: @HaseebKhan Good luck ;)

Comment: @FarhadZamani .. this needs them to be registered in the configureservice correct ?

Comment: @HanyHabib Of course. you need register all classes that implements `IMongoMappee` interface like this. `services.AddScoped<IMongoMapper, CourseMap>();`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have empty constructor for the derived classes as mentioned in your example,you can do the below code you can get the interface by reflection and check which type can be assignable and `!c.IsInterface` so as it doesn't return the interface itself:

```
  var result = typeof("Any Class").Assembly.GetTypes().Where(c => typeof(IMongoMapper).IsAssignableFrom(c) && !c.IsInterface);
  foreach (var i in result)
  {
    ((IMongoMapper)Activator.CreateInstance(i)).Configure();
  }
```

Comment: The first code sample answers the question. It discovers the types that implement the interface and calls the `Configure` method on each one. But it's unclear why it takes an `IServiceCollection` as a parameter and returns it. The method has nothing to do with `IServiceCollection`. It doesn't use the argument. You could just remove that.

Comment: I was adding extra code if you want to use it in the configure service to add it as extension method and it returns it if you wanna continue chaining..

Comment: If it's an extension that does something with the services that would make more sense. But it's not clear why it would be an extension used with `services` if it doesn't do anything with them. An extension is just shorthand for calling a method and passing a parameter. There's no reason to pass a parameter to a method that isn't used.

Comment: if it helped, kindly don't forget to mark it as a valid ans ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IPersonals, Personals>();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it via Reflection.

I just tried the code below and it works in dotnet core 3.1.
It works with the interface and the implementation class:

- in the same assembly
- in separate assemblies

```cs
var asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(YourClass));
var mapperTypes = asm.GetTypes().Where(x => x.GetInterface(nameof(IMongoMapper)) != null);
foreach(var mapperType in mapperTypes)
{
    var mapper = (IMongoMapper)Activator.CreateInstance(mapperType);
    mapper.Configure();
}
```

You can also plug any parameters you need to create an instance of your objects:

```cs
IConfiguration _configuration;
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
}

//other code

foreach(var mapperType in mapperTypes)
{
    var mapper = (IMongoMapper)Activator.CreateInstance(mapperType, _configuration);
    mapper.Configure();
}
```

There is also this question that has lots of examples (some do not work in dotnet core anymore): [Getting all types that implement an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface)