# How to get all types in solution projects?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, system.reflection

I have a solution and multiple .net core projects.

- Project (solution)

  - WebApi
  - Business
  - Data

`WebApi` project references `Business`, but does not reference `Data` project. So I want to get all types in solution that implements `IMyInterface`. All projects has classes that implements `IMyInterface`. I want to find all of them.

I am calling following code in WebApi project:

```
        var m = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(name => name.GetTypes())
            .Where(type => typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            .ToList();
```

But not types found.

How can I find?

Comment: you can't get types in projects. You can get them only in assemblies.

Comment: @T.S. yes I mean in assemblies. Do you have any solution?

Comment: **1.** answer provided below **2.** your question is still not fixed - it says "solution projects". **3.** `Directory.GetFiles... Assembly.Load`. **4.** google - "c# get assembly times that implement interface"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting all types that implement an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get all assembly projects like this

```cs
public Assembly[] GetAssemblies()
{
      var dataAssembly = typeof(AnClassInDataLayer).Assembly;
      var businessAssembly = typeof(ACLassInBusinessLayer).Assembly;
      var webApiAssembly = typeof(Startup).Assembly;
      return new Assembly[] { businessAssembly , dataAssembly, webApiAssembly  };
}
```

then

```cs
var m = GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany(name => name.GetTypes())// or .SelectMany(a => a.ExportedTypes)
        .Where(type => typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        .ToList();
```

**Update**

In .Net Core if `WebApi` project referenced `business` layer and `Business` layer reference the `Data` layer, so in `WebApi` layer you can access to `Data` layer

Comment: But Data layer does not referenced in WebApi, So I can not use `typeof(AnClassInDataLayer).Assembly`.

Comment: @barteloma i updated my answer. and i hope helpful for you