# Can I store a list of types and access their static properties through an interface?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, types, interface

Let's say I have an interface ICar:

```
public interface ICar
{
    static int WheelSize { get; }
}
```

And I have two classes that implement the interface:

```
class FirstCar: ICar
{
    static int WheelSize { get; } = 28;
}

class SecondCar : ICar
{
    static int WheelSize { get; } = 24;
}
```

I would like to store these types in a list, and retrieve their static properties without having to call GetProperty("propName")Value(Null) on the type object:

```
List<Type> cars = new List<Type>();

cars.Add(typeof(FirstCar));
cars.Add(typeof(SecondCar));

foreach (Type car in cars)
{
    // I want to do something like this:
    int size = ICar<car>.WheelSize;

    // But I currently have to do this:
    size = (int)car.GetProperty("WheelSize").GetValue(null);
    // or this:
    size = (int)car.GetProperty(nameof(ICar.WheelSize)).GetValue(null);
 }
```

Is there any way to store a list of types that implement a known interface, and access their static properties in a strongly-typed manner?

I would (maybe naively) love to store a list of generics directly rather than having to create type objects, but I don't think that's even remotely possible?

**To give further information about the problem that I would like to solve:**

I would like to display a dropdown box that shows the types of cars that you can create (so in this example, a list that contains a FirstCar type and a SecondCar type). I would like to display their respective WheelSizes without needing to create instances of each (the properties are static so why should I need to create instances?). As a result, I store a list of the types that can be created, rather than instances of the objects. Unfortunately the only way I can then access the WheelSize property from the Type object, is by using a string to retrieve the value based on the property name, which doesn't feel right.

Follow Up:
As pointed out by Guru Stron , I can change the interface property to a string and it still compiles. The class properties are therefore not the same as the interface property, and as a result, I cannot expect to be able to resolve them through the interface. I cant say I understand why they are not the same, but the fact that they aren't must be the (or a) reason why I can't do what I want.

Comment: The problem with your theory is that those are *two different classes.*  `WheelSize` lives with the class, not with the object instances, and those are two distinct static properties, not one.

Comment: Can you talk a little bit more about the actual problem you're trying to solve?  Do you want to store a list of types, or do you just want a way to share a common property across all of your class instances?

Comment: The code does compile and run for me in a Core 3.1 project, and I get the correct sizes using GetProperty.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you [can](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface): Beginning with C# 8.0, an interface may define a default implementation for members. It may also define static members in order to provide a single implementation for common functionality.

Comment: The problem to solve is that I would like to display a list of the different types of car that can be created by a user, without actually having to create instances of each car to retrieve their respective properties. In this car analogy, each car needs different implementations for certain methods, so I would to keep the car types separated into different classes.

Comment: Use Reflection to produce that list.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface

Comment: The challenge is not that I am unable to produce that list, but that I cannot access the static properties in a "nice" way once I have that list

Comment: Then use the Default Implementation interface functionality that @guru describes.

Comment: But all I have is a list of Types? How would I access the interface property through the type object? Or should I not be storing these classes as types in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var dict = new[] { typeof(FirstCar), typeof(SecondCar) }
    .Select(t => new 
     {
         Type = t,
         Func = (Func<int>) t.GetProperty("WheelSize", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).GetMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int>))            
     })
    .ToDictionary(d => d.Type, d => d.Func);

Console.WriteLine(dict[typeof(FirstCar)]()); //28
```

Comment: Is this not similar to the code that I already use to access the property? It still forces me to access the properties through a string, rather than having it strongly-typed.

Comment: Then I don't follow your problem.

Comment: I have two types that I know implement a static property. Can I retrieve those static property values using strong typing? The proposed solution just moves that weak-typing somewhere else.

Comment: @Soy31 declare `WheelSize` on car types as public and use `SecondCar.WheelSize`

Comment: @Soy31 it seems you have misconception about static interfaces. Your car types does not implement `ICar.WheelSize` they even return different type.  You can remove `WheelSize` from concrete types and code still compiles.

Comment: I cant use the generic SecondCar because I cannot store it anywhere without converting to a type object. I do not know at compile time exactly what class I want to retrieve the property from, but I do know that it will implement the interface.

Comment: I did not notice the type difference! I suppose fact that it was able to compile like that explains why I can't do what I want

Comment: @Soy31, again, your `First/SecondCar`  types does not implement  `ICar.WheelSize` static property.

Comment: @Soy31: Do I understand correctly that you want to set `WheelSize` for `FirstCar` through an Interface, and have that size be the same for all instances of `FirstCar`?  And that you want to do the same for `SecondCar`, but all instances of `SecondCar` have a different `WheelSize` than your instances of `FirstCar`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Although I do not want to be forced to create an instance of each car to access the property (like displaying a list of the types of car a user could create before actually creating one).

Comment: Interfaces are a runtime concept.  I tried doing static members on an interface in C# 8, but they just kept returning zeroes.

Comment: See, here's the problem.  If you put a static member in an interface or base class, it lives with that interface, so anything that inherits it will get the same value for all types.  And since you can't override static types in a base type or interface, I think you are stuck.  Runtime polymorphism is runtime.