# Copying properties from one generic class to another through a value converter

Tags: c#, generics, data-manipulation

In my C# application I have a class that acts as a data structure to hold various categories, which may hold sub-categories or lists of categories, which eventually hold data properties that hold values and other associated data.

The `DataStructure` class is generic, because it is used in multiple places in the application either directly or as a base class for extensions, and the type of values in `DataProperty` will be different in each use case. At some point I need to transfer values from instance of `DataStructure` of one type to instance of `DataStructure` of another type. For example, if first `DataStructure` was of type `string`, and the second was of type `double`, the converter will cast value of each `DataProperty` through some custom logic. Any lists of categories also need to be filled in the second `DataStructure`, so that everything matches the first `DataStructure`.

So essentially I need to make a copy of instance of `DataStructure` but with another type, converting values with a custom converter. This also needs to work if the second data structure is an instance of a class that derives from `DataStructure`. This is the simplified version of the code that shows the setup:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataStructure<string> dataStructureStr = new();
    FillData(dataStructureStr); //Fills lists of categories, writes some string type values into DataProperty properties
    DataStructure<double> dataStructureDbl = new();
    ConvertAndCopyData(dataStructureStr, dataStructureDbl); //Transfers values of all properties from one DataStructure to another using a converter
}

public interface ICategory
{
    //...
}

public abstract class Category : ICategory
{
    //...
}

public class DataProperty<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    //...
}

public class DataStructure<T> 
{
    public EnvironmentData Environment { get; init; } = new();

    public class EnvironmentData : Category
    {
        public LightData Light { get; init; } = new();
        public List<Force> Forces { get; init; } = new();

        public class LightData : Category
        {
            public LightPositionData LightPosition { get; init; } = new();
            public DataProperty<T> Intensity { get; init; } = new();

            public class LightPositionData : Category
            {
                public DataProperty<List<T>> OriginCoordsXYZ { get; init; } = new();
                public DataProperty<List<T>> TargetCoordsXYZ { get; init; } = new();
            }
        }
        public class Force : Category
        {
            public DataProperty<T> Magnitude { get; init; } = new();
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

While the `ConvertAndCopyData` function could be implemented by explicitly addressing each category, sub-category and data property, it would require me to essentially type out the whole structure once again, and maintain this function manually if I change anything in the original `DataStructure`. The `DataStructure` in my actual application is far more extensive, rendering this approach impractical.

I am hoping that this can be achieved through reflection, as performance is not critical here. But I have no idea how to do it. Can anyone advise?

Comment: Your example classes `EnvironmentData`, `LightData`, etc. are all nested in each other. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Progman, yes, that is correct. For example, LightData is a sub-category of EnvironmentData, therefore it is nested.

Comment: use automapper? https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Comment: @RandRandom I tried using it, but apparently it doesn't have automatic map creation anymore, so I would still have to explicitly type out the entire category hierarchy for it to work - that is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: as was suggested in the comments of the answer you could use reflection to feed the type mappings to automapper BUT somewhere there would need to be an explicit logic which types should be mapped at all, and then which types should map with which counter type - the „explicit logic“ could be anything eg. attributes on class level, a naming convention (eg. all types with starting with  Data), a namespace convention  (eg. all types below namspace MyData.Structure.Basic;) or some other idea

Comment: automapper „only“ eliminates the necessity to explicitly write code copy memberA to memberA, but you still need to tell it which classes should be mapped

Comment: @RandRandom Thank you for the clarification. I reviewed the documentation of AutoMapper, but I don't see a way of how to tell it to map categories hierarchy without explicitly typing each one, and only explicitly define how to convert, for example, `DataProperty<string>` to `DataProperty<double>`. I tried something like this here: [link](https://pastebin.com/U8V4NdWH), but it isn't working. Can you help me figure out how to make it work with my specific case?

Comment: don’t have time to look at it right away, for now I have only moved your code to dotnetfiddle to have it executable and see the error https://dotnetfiddle.net/54HMkp | maybe tomorrow, or the day after

Comment: @Progman - maybe you can chime in, and have a look

Comment: Appreciate it. Yeah, I was getting the exact same error. @Progman saw this code I believe. The issue here was that I was trying to get auto-map to work, but it has been depreciated. I have no idea how to set up mapping for my use case with reflection instead so that I don't have to type out the category hierarchy though. If you could take a look at it whenever you have time, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`AutoMapper`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/) to convert an object to another object. You have to create a mapping for the classes with the generic types, see [AutoMapper - Features - Open Generics](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Open-Generics.html). The mapping could look like this:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    IList<Type> types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(it => it.IsAssignableTo(typeof(ICategory)))
        .ToList();
    foreach (Type type in types)
    {
        cfg.CreateMap(type, type);
    }
    cfg.CreateMap(typeof(DataStructure<>), typeof(DataStructure<>));
    cfg.CreateMap(typeof(DataProperty<>), typeof(DataProperty<>));
});
```

You can use reflection to get all the classes, that implements the `ICategory` interface (see [Getting all types that implement an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface)) and add the types via `CreateMap()` to the mapper configuration. Since `DataStructure<T>` and `DataProperty<T>` does not have such a base class or other kind of indication, you have to explicit add the mappings for these classes.

When you create your mapper with `config.CreateMapper();` you can map your objects with:

```
mapper.Map(dataStructureStr, dataStructureDbl);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I am trying this out, although I don't understand why you left out "<>" empty in the last map (DataProperty). Shouldn't it be `string` and `double` respectively, with a specified converter?
The issue with this approach is that I still have to specify all these category mappings when calling `MapperConfiguration`. It will require me to type out all the category hierachy again, which is what I'm trying to avoid. Also mapper docs say there can be only one mapping per application, while I will need many different mappings - is there a workaround?

Comment: @aluc_2513 I haven't left out the `<>` at the mapping for `DataProperty<>`. Automapper already have a mapping from `string` to `double`. Maybe `AddMaps()` can be used to find all classes for mapping, see https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#assembly-scanning-for-auto-configuration. You can have multiple different mappings in your application, just create a new mapping with `new MapperConfiguration()` and `config.CreateMapper()`. Where does it say that you can have only one mapping per application?

Comment: In the getting started, it says "You only need one MapperConfiguration instance typically per AppDomain and should be instantiated during startup" and also "Configuration should only happen once per AppDomain". About converter, what if I wanted to use my own string->double converter? In [link](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Open-Generics.html) it mentions `ConvertUsing`, but there don't seem to be any examples on how to declare that converter. I did try using your code as you wrote it, but it threw exception `Error mapping types.` without much clarification.

Comment: @aluc_2513 "Should" and "typically" does not mean "must". Usually you only need one mapping, so you put it at the start of the application, but you can have multiple mappings. In fact, AutoMapper used to have `static` properties for the mappings, see https://docs.automapper.org/en/v12.0.1/9.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#the-static-api-was-removed. You might be able to use `CreateMap<string, double>()` if you want a different logic for mapping these types, but I haven't tried this. In case of errors, AutoMapper usually generate very detailed exception messages, see https://pastebin.com/uM2GddNk

Comment: @aluc_2513 https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html explains how to use custom converters for your mapping.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and links, I believe I set it up as per docs, but I still can't get it to work. If it's not too much trouble, could you please check if I did something wrong? My code: [link](https://pastebin.com/U8V4NdWH). I am getting 'Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.' exception with no specifics. AddMaps should have created maps for copying category hierarchy and lists, while CreateMap specifies converter for `DataProperty`. Am I doing it wrong here? I tried maybe 10 different ways and still can't get to a working solution.

Comment: @aluc_2513 Based on https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Attribute-mapping.html?highlight=addmaps#type-map-configuration and https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/104a192407858fe3a54a8a937ca95a34fd7c6959/src/AutoMapper/Configuration/MapperConfigurationExpression.cs#L162C23-L162C23 `AddMaps()` will only look for profiles and special attributes. https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/9.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#automapper-no-longer-creates-maps-automatically-createmissingtypemaps-and-conventions even mention they don't automatically add mappings, so you have to do it explicit/via reflection.

Comment: Well, that was what my initial question was about... Explicit is impractical, and I don't know how to do it via reflection, I was hoping someone could show me how to do it.

Comment: @aluc_2513 I have adjusted the answer to use reflection to find the category types to map.

Comment: Appreciate you modifying that code. It still throws `Error mapping types.` when I try to run with it. That specific exception doesn't seem to tell what mapping is missing for it, the only useful thing I found in exception details is `Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping`. Any ideas? P.S. I could add `IDataProperty` interface and have `DataProperty<T>` implement it if it would help map creation. As for `DataStructure`, it could extend `Category`, there is no harm in that either. But I am not sure if that error is related to this.

Comment: @aluc_2513 You have to read the full complete exception message, not just the first line (it is a multi line exception message string). Using reflection works fine, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZH4oqd. Keep in mind that your `LightPositionData` class in https://pastebin.com/U8V4NdWH does not extends from `Category`, unlike the code you have shown in your question.

Comment: Yes, you are correct about that extension, I missed it. The code you wrote there works now, and I finally understand how it is supposed to work. Thank you very much, I will proceed to use this to the real application.